# Screenshot of the Week #85

Tags: discussion, community-event, screenshot-of-the-week

## This contest is over.

*[previous contest](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/16681) | [next contest](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/16707)*

---

Hello and welcome to the 85th Screenshot of the Week!

To start with, congratulations to the winner of the previous contest! [nobody's](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/16682/163757) picture from [trails-of-cold-steel-3](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/trails-of-cold-steel-3) won with 9 upvotes!

[image: Last week's winning screenshot one]

---

To submit a screenshot, simply post it as an answer to this question, but please take note of the following:

- One screenshot per post, and one post per person, please!
- Limited picture modifications are allowed, such as cropping, simple filters, and blurring of identifying info such as names, but not adding other images or text.
- To ensure a fair playing field, please post screenshots you've taken yourself rather than ones you found online.
- Stack Exchange’s [Code of Conduct](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/conduct) still applies - so if it would be unacceptable to post normally, it’s unacceptable here.

Also, try to avoid pictures that include spoilers. We want everyone to be able to enjoy this contest, so the less spoilers the better.

#### How long will the contest run?

We will accept submissions for a week, until 19:00 UTC of 2023-02-27, then have a second week-long period where only voting will be accepted. This is to give every submission, even those posted at the end of the first week, a chance to be voted on by everyone.

After the end of the second week, at 19:00 UTC of 2023-03-06 we will count upvotes only to determine the winning screenshot, which will be featured for a week on the main site's photo widget.

---

## No Theme

There is no theme this week.

As a reminder, we're always accepting suggestions for themed weeks, and have compiled that suggestion process into a [question of its own](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15029/screenshot-of-the-week-themes).  Additionally, there is the [hall of fame](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14939/screenshot-of-the-week-hall-of-fame) you can check out that contains all the previous contest winners.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[image]

[horizon-zero-dawn](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/horizon-zero-dawn) has some awe-inspiring locations

Comment: Really cool. And also mysterious: Is this currently being built? Is it old and people are now using it or taking it apart? Did it just come there and destroy something, but the structures are still barely holding up? And the technological difference from the protagonist's simple clothes and the wooden structures to that machine/beast implies quite an interesting world: Aliens? Ancient extinct civilization? Two competing intelligent species on one planet?

Comment: @FabianRöling it's an ancient technology, the game is set in a post-apocalyptic future. It's worth not to spoil, play the game :)

Comment: reminds me a little movie Matrix.

Comment: This must have been the same vibe that Hyrule had going on when they were digging up the Divine Beasts in Breath of the Wild.

Comment: This is such an awesome image :) Looks very cool on the main page!

Answer (score 6):

[image: Dark Knight Lv 56 Glam in Final Fantasy XIV]

My Lv 56 Dark Knight Glam with my long time partner Fran in [final-fantasy-xiv](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/final-fantasy-xiv)

Answer (score 6):

The lifestream protects the planet in [final-fantasy-vii](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/final-fantasy-vii) [image]

Answer (score 5):

I should really look into getting my clothes fixed in [hogwarts-legacy](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hogwarts-legacy)

[image: Clothes are indeed ...magical]

Comment: Nothing a good ironing couldn't fix!

Comment: *Clothingia ironinga*!

Answer (score 5):

[image: A monkey sailing on a boat in the middle of the sea in [tag:minecraft-java-edition].]

A monkey sailing on a boat in the middle of the sea in [minecraft-java-edition](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-java-edition).

Comment: Throw in some sharks and it is the plot of the film Open Water. +1

Comment: lol @LoreFriendly