# Screenshot of the Week #86: How Fashionable!

Tags: discussion, community-event, screenshot-of-the-week

## This contest is over

*[previous contest](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/16693) | [next contest](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/16717)*

---

Hello and welcome to the **86<sup>th</sup>** edition of the Screenshot of the Week!

To start with, congratulations to the winner of the previous contest! [Batophobia's](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/16697/8350) picture from [horizon-zero-dawn](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/horizon-zero-dawn) won with 12 upvotes!

[image: Last week's winning screenshot one]

---

To submit a screenshot, simply post it as an answer to this question, but please take note of the following:

- One screenshot per post, and one post per person, please!
- Limited picture modifications are allowed, such as cropping, simple filters, and blurring of identifying info such as names, but not adding other images or text.
- To ensure a fair playing field, please post screenshots you've taken yourself rather than ones you found online.
- Stack Exchange’s [Code of Conduct](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/conduct) still applies - so if it would be unacceptable to post normally, it’s unacceptable here.

Also, try to avoid pictures that include spoilers. We want everyone to be able to enjoy this contest, so the less spoilers the better.

#### How long will the contest run?

We will accept submissions for a week, until 19:00 UTC of 2023-03-13, then have a second week-long period where only voting will be accepted. This is to give every submission, even those posted at the end of the first week, a chance to be voted on by everyone.

After the end of the second week, at 19:00 UTC of 2023-03-20, we will count upvotes only to determine the winning screenshot, which will be featured for a week on the main site's photo widget.

---

## How Fashionable!

Check out these duds! Showcase your character wearing their fanciest, funniest, rarest, coolest, grungiest -- whatever attire you'd like to show off.

As a reminder, we're always accepting suggestions for themed weeks, and have compiled that suggestion process into a [question of its own](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15029/screenshot-of-the-week-themes).  Additionally, there is the [hall of fame](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14939/screenshot-of-the-week-hall-of-fame) you can check out that contains all the previous contest winners.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[image]
Ready to Rock and Stone in [deep-rock-galactic](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/deep-rock-galactic)

Comment: Did I hear a Rock and Stone!?

Comment: ROCK AND STONE BRUTHA

Comment: To the bone!​ ​

Answer (score 9):

[image: Final Fantasy XIV]

Me enjoying some tea at The Bismarck in Limsa Lominsa in my finest of outfits [final-fantasy-xiv](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/final-fantasy-xiv)

Answer (score 7):

[image: Buckets rule supreme]

The game has just begun and I have found the best helmet one could hope for - a bucket in [divinity-original-sin-2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/divinity-original-sin-2)

Answer (score 5):

[image]

Made the most OP villain in [lego-dc-super-villains](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lego-dc-super-villains)

Comment: Possibly relevant: https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/114033/how-can-santa-keep-his-lists-when-the-gdpr-is-around from Worldbuildung SE