# Screenshot of the Week #88: Easter (Eggs)

Tags: discussion, community-event, screenshot-of-the-week

## This contest is over.

*[previous contest](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/16717) | [next contest](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/16753)*

---

Hello and welcome to the **88<sup>th</sup>** edition of the Screenshot of the Week!

To start with, congratulations to the winner of the previous contest! [GammaGames'](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/16718/222022) moody picture from [hogwarts-legacy](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hogwarts-legacy) of dancing apparitions won with 10 upvotes!

[image: Last week's winning screenshot one]

---

To submit a screenshot, simply post it as an answer to this question, but please take note of the following:

- One screenshot per post, and one post per person, please!
- Limited picture modifications are allowed, such as cropping, simple filters, and blurring of identifying info such as names, but not adding other images or text.
- To ensure a fair playing field, please post screenshots you've taken yourself rather than ones you found online.
- Stack Exchange’s [Code of Conduct](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/conduct) still applies - so if it would be unacceptable to post normally, it’s unacceptable here.

Also, try to avoid pictures that include spoilers. We want everyone to be able to enjoy this contest, so the less spoilers the better.

#### How long will the contest run?

We will accept submissions for a week, until 19:00 UTC of 2023-04-10, then have a second week-long period where only voting will be accepted. This is to give every submission, even those posted at the end of the first week, a chance to be voted on by everyone.

After the end of the second week, at 19:00 UTC of 2023-04-17, we will count upvotes only to determine the winning screenshot, which will be featured for a week on the main site's photo widget.

---

## Easter (Eggs)

According to certain calendars it will be Easter soon. Christian and pagan rituals not entirely aside, it can also be a time to celebrate the arrival of spring, which tends to be regarded with quite some optimism (in the temperate zones, at least).

No matter how you feel about it, I'm sure you can find imagery of appropriate scenery or events: bunnies, resurrections, blossoming flowers, Easter eggs (of the [painted](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Easter_egg) or [unpainted](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Easter_egg_(media)) variety), Iðunn or other related personalities from our wonderful spectrum of deities, &c. Happy Easter already!

As a reminder, we're always accepting suggestions for themed weeks, and have compiled that suggestion process into a [question of its own](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15029/screenshot-of-the-week-themes).  Additionally, there is the [hall of fame](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14939/screenshot-of-the-week-hall-of-fame) you can check out that contains all the previous contest winners.

Comment: No idea what the mod team would do without watching our backs with this screenshot posts. Well, I know what we'd do... we'd likely post these a few days late constantly haha. Thanks as always!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[image: Mih Khetto's Amphitheatre during Hatching-tide in Final Fantasy XIV]

Mih Khetto's Amphitheatre decked out for Hatching-tide 2023 (Eorzea's version of Easter) in [final-fantasy-xiv](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/final-fantasy-xiv), featuring a special guest this year, a big Tonberry

Answer (score 10):

The space rig in DRG has been decorated with bunnies, eggs, carrots, and flowers. Time for an egg hunt!
[image: Easter decorations on the Abyss Bar][deep-rock-galactic](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/deep-rock-galactic)

Answer (score 7):

The [oldschool-runescape](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/oldschool-runescape) Easter bunny awaits your help in Varrock.

[image]

Answer (score 6):

At least we'll still have Easter Eggs in 12000 years... or, uhm... Squidster Eggs? [splatoon-3](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/splatoon-3)

[image]