# Screenshot of the Week #89

Tags: discussion, community-event, screenshot-of-the-week

## The contest is over.

*[previous contest](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/16745) | [next contest](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/16764)*

---

Hello and welcome to the **89<sup>th</sup>** edition of the Screenshot of the Week!

To start with, congratulations to the winner of the previous contest! [Memor-X's](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/16748/163757) picture from [final-fantasy-xiv](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/final-fantasy-xiv) with 11 upvotes!

[image: Last week's winning screenshot one]

---

To submit a screenshot, simply post it as an answer to this question, but please take note of the following:

- One screenshot per post, and one post per person, please!
- Limited picture modifications are allowed, such as cropping, simple filters, and blurring of identifying info such as names, but not adding other images or text.
- To ensure a fair playing field, please post screenshots you've taken yourself rather than ones you found online.
- Stack Exchange’s [Code of Conduct](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/conduct) still applies - so if it would be unacceptable to post normally, it’s unacceptable here.

Also, try to avoid pictures that include spoilers. We want everyone to be able to enjoy this contest, so the less spoilers the better.

#### How long will the contest run?

We will accept submissions for a week, until 19:00 UTC of 2023-04-24, then have a second week-long period where only voting will be accepted. This is to give every submission, even those posted at the end of the first week, a chance to be voted on by everyone.

After the end of the second week, at 19:00 UTC of 2023-05-01, we will count upvotes only to determine the winning screenshot, which will be featured for a week on the main site's photo widget.

---

## No Theme

There is no theme this week.

As a reminder, we're always accepting suggestions for themed weeks, and have compiled that suggestion process into a [question of its own](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15029/screenshot-of-the-week-themes).  Additionally, there is the [hall of fame](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14939/screenshot-of-the-week-hall-of-fame) you can check out that contains all the previous contest winners.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[image]

Quico is just as confused as I am by the architecture in [papo-and-yo](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/papo-and-yo).

<sub>(I think that's the right tag. The game is "[Papo & Yo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Papo_&_Yo)" but you can't have special characters in tags...)</sub>

Answer (score 7):

[image: yuel]

The future changed. Yuel is forced to see it in [final-fantasy-13-2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/final-fantasy-13-2)

Answer (score 5):

Nvidia Ansel's super resolution mode has been acting up in [the-witcher-3](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-witcher-3), ever since the Next-Gen update :(

[image]

Comment: Is it evident in the photo how Ansel is acting up or am I missing something? All I see is a beautiful aerial vista.

Comment: @LoreFriendly It is evident, but not immediately obvious :) The problem is with the 'stitching' part of the multi-res screen-archery process: once the different screenshot are made, Ansel is supposed to reunite them in the order in which they were shot (or "seen"), but for some reason it now mixes things up. You can see a lot of blurred edges upon examination, and the perspective is off (see e.g. the lower right corner [click image for larger version]).

Comment: (But indeed I took an example that was not too obvious, as they tend to look like bad Photoshopped screenshots, on the wrong end of "artistic". This [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vscm0.jpg), originally shot at the same resolution, gives a similar but better view of how the process parameters are off.)

Answer (score 5):

And you think you have problems...

[image: Some guard is about to become rat food in A Plague Tale: Requiem]

Some guard is about to become rat food in [a-plague-tale-requiem](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/a-plague-tale-requiem)

Answer (score 4):

Me and my friend noping out of some cursed building in [phasmophobia](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/phasmophobia)

[image]

Comment: Great game.  I've been playing Demonologist as well.

Answer (score 3):

[image: H'aanit in Octopath Traveler]

H'aanit in [octopath-traveler](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/octopath-traveler) breaking the damage limit as she rips up a mansion