# Screenshot of the Week #90

Tags: discussion, community-event, screenshot-of-the-week

## This contest is over.

*[previous contest](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/16753) | [next contest](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/16773)*

---

Hello and welcome to the **90<sup>th</sup>** edition of the Screenshot of the Week!

To start with, congratulations to the winner of the previous contest! [Roddy of the Frozen Peas's](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/16756/87579) picture from [papo-and-yo](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/papo-and-yo) with 11 upvotes!

[image: Last week's winning screenshot one]

---

To submit a screenshot, simply post it as an answer to this question, but please take note of the following:

- One screenshot per post, and one post per person, please!
- Limited picture modifications are allowed, such as cropping, simple filters, and blurring of identifying info such as names, but not adding other images or text.
- To ensure a fair playing field, please post screenshots you've taken yourself rather than ones you found online.
- Stack Exchange’s [Code of Conduct](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/conduct) still applies - so if it would be unacceptable to post normally, it’s unacceptable here.

Also, try to avoid pictures that include spoilers. We want everyone to be able to enjoy this contest, so the less spoilers the better.

#### How long will the contest run?

We will accept submissions for a week, until 19:00 UTC of 2023-05-08, then have a second week-long period where only voting will be accepted. This is to give every submission, even those posted at the end of the first week, a chance to be voted on by everyone.

After the end of the second week, at 19:00 UTC of 2023-05-15, we will count upvotes only to determine the winning screenshot, which will be featured for a week on the main site's photo widget.

---

## No Theme

There is no theme this week.

As a reminder, we're always accepting suggestions for themed weeks, and have compiled that suggestion process into a [question of its own](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15029/screenshot-of-the-week-themes).  Additionally, there is the [hall of fame](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14939/screenshot-of-the-week-hall-of-fame) you can check out that contains all the previous contest winners.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[image]

The beautiful, but rather empty, world of [satisfactory](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/satisfactory).

<sub>Probably need to come up with a better caption. Just wanted to share this rather picturesque alien biome.</sub>

Comment: I'm really looking forward to playing it!

Comment: It's pretty interesting, early access clearly but it's got enough features actually play. Definitely nowhere near complete, though. I recommend giving it a go.

Comment: And it has been in EA for a while already. Is it still buggy, simply, or are there features lacking that make it boring at times?

Comment: The game feels ... _empty_, really. There are bugs, yes. I've clipped through terrain and gotten stuck and had to reload from save a few times. And supposedly there's significantly more bugs in multiplayer (I don't play multiplayer games.) But there's a distinct feeling of "ok now what?" as you progress through the tech tree which isn't all that big. It just feels like there should be more to it -- more (types of) enemies, more challenges, more things to find and discover. I called it a "beautiful but empty" world in my screenshot caption and the more I consider the more accurate it is.

Comment: The thing with Satisfactory is kind of to streamline your factory (rebuild it all again but better, more efficient, more organized, higher capacity). Not for everyone. It's not an open world RPG, it's not a Minecraft sandbox, it's not a survival base builder.

Answer (score 9):

Jumping into the Duviri Paradox in [warframe](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/warframe)

[image]

Answer (score 9):

A quiet hallway in Karnaca (reminiscent of a [Hammershøi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vilhelm_Hammersh%C3%B8i)).

I keep getting blown away by the beauty of the lighting and especially the textures, materials, and meshes, even in this noticeably inferior entry in its series, [dishonored-death-of-the-outsider](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dishonored-death-of-the-outsider).

[image]

Comment: I did not expect to further my art history education while browsing Arqade. Nicely done.

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas Thanks! I'll make it a [series](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/15684/222022) :D

Comment: I remember a game called Monument Valley in which each frame looked like an M.C. Escher painting. Your screenshots do look very beautiful. Thanks for sharing them and making a series out of them.

Comment: @LoreFriendly Yeah, but only technically, in the sense that both explore constructions that are impossible (in Euclidean space) from an isometric perspective and involving staircases and pathways—artistically, they are quite far apart. (And thank you :)

Comment: Love the aspect ratio, the detail on that floor is fantastic!

Answer (score 7):

Bus driver just goes ahead and drives through this plane, and parks there for a bit. Perfectly normal. [microsoft-flight-simulator](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/microsoft-flight-simulator)

[image]

Answer (score 7):

Watch out for hungry enemies on your journeys! [image: Game is]
From the PSX game [heart-of-darkness](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/heart-of-darkness)

Answer (score 6):

For the first time and I think for the last time they are agreed.

[image: sara]

[trails-of-cold-steel](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/trails-of-cold-steel)

Answer (score 4):

Renovating in [hades](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hades), still lots of work for the House Contractor.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The vast scenery of **A Plague Tale: Requiem** is amazing, but every now and then I take a screenshot of something that I thought is a bit "different" than the rest.

[image: Sophia, from A Plague Tale: Requiem, shining the light for us.]

Sophia, from [a-plague-tale-requiem](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/a-plague-tale-requiem), shining the light for us.