# Screenshot of the Week #91 - Achievements!

Tags: discussion, community-event, screenshot-of-the-week

## This contest is over

*[previous contest](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/16764) | [next contest](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/16777)*

---

Hello and welcome to the 91st Screenshot of the Week!

To start with, congratulations to the winner of the previous contest! [Roddy of the Frozen Peas'](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/16769/222022) screenshot of scenery from [satisfactory](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/satisfactory) won with 12 upvotes!

[image: Last week's winning screenshot one]

---

To submit a screenshot, simply post it as an answer to this question, but please take note of the following:

- One screenshot per post, and one post per person, please!
- Limited picture modifications are allowed, such as cropping, simple filters, and blurring of identifying info such as names, but not adding other images or text.
- To ensure a fair playing field, please post screenshots you've taken yourself rather than ones you found online.
- Stack Exchange’s [Code of Conduct](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/conduct) still applies - so if it would be unacceptable to post normally, it’s unacceptable here.

Also, try to avoid pictures that include spoilers. We want everyone to be able to enjoy this contest, so the less spoilers the better.

#### How long will the contest run?

We will accept submissions for a week, until 19:00 UTC of 2023-05-22, then have a second week-long period where only voting will be accepted. This is to give every submission, even those posted at the end of the first week, a chance to be voted on by everyone.

After the end of the second week, at 19:00 UTC of 2023-05-29 we will count upvotes only to determine the winning screenshot, which will be featured for a week on the main site's photo widget.

---

## Achievements!

Show off your hard work: your promotion in a competitive game, you standing victorious over that one Boss, you dinging to max-level, or having received that rare and highly sought-after achievement.

As a reminder, we're always accepting suggestions for themed weeks, and have compiled that suggestion process into a [question of its own](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15029/screenshot-of-the-week-themes).  Additionally, there is the [hall of fame](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14939/screenshot-of-the-week-hall-of-fame) you can check out that contains all the previous contest winners.

Comment: Thanks Joachim, I forgot to close the previous one!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Perfectly clearing the board set to maximum width on [tetr.io](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tetr.io) (100 blocks wide). Definitely one of the sillier achievements.

[image]

Comment: But it's not a quad

Comment: @MBraedley I originally planned on doing that after I got this screenshot, but after some attempts I realized it was past 3AM and probably time to go to sleep.

Answer (score 9):

[psychonauts](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/psychonauts) The Collective Unconscious congratulates you on gathering all collectibles.

[image: ALL LEVELS 100% COMPLETE! CONGRATULATIONS, PSYCHONASTER Raz!]

Comment: Oh my, someone is a completionist. :-)

Comment: Sure, but plenty of games allow you to be a completionist.  This one is unusual in adding the text block floating around the hub area once the collection is complete.

Comment: Having the text is good. That is a nice touch so you're not always guessing.

Comment: @JonathanDavidArndt worse are the games that allow you to get to 120% completion :(

Comment: YES! So true. That drives me nuts... really, anything where you're not really sure if you missed anything is annoying. On the flip side, circa 1999, I remember playing Super Mario World, and that one maxes out at 101% with a star: a nice visual indicator that you found everything.

Answer (score 8):

Not a great achivement; but it tooks hours of searching.

[image: gold chocobo]

Chocobo search in [final-fantasy-9](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/final-fantasy-9)

Comment: What's it say in English?

Comment: You chocobo gain the ability to fly.

Comment: ad litteram: "Oh Choco, you have acquired the ability to fly through the air!" (or "through the skies", it's technically an expression)