# Screenshot of the Week #92

Tags: discussion, community-event, screenshot-of-the-week

## This contest is over.

*[previous contest](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/16773/) | [next contest](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/16797/)*

---

Hello and welcome to the **92<sup>nd</sup>** edition of the Screenshot of the Week!

To start with, congratulations to the winner of the previous contest! [Quijibo's](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/16775/222022) picture from [tetr.io](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tetr.io) won with 16 upvotes!

[image: Last week's winning screenshot one]

Let's see if this aspect ratio behaves properly in the widget on the main page :)

---

To submit a screenshot, simply post it as an answer to this question, but please take note of the following:

- One screenshot per post, and one post per person, please!
- Limited picture modifications are allowed, such as cropping, simple filters, and blurring of identifying info such as names, but not adding other images or text.
- To ensure a fair playing field, please post screenshots you've taken yourself rather than ones you found online.
- Stack Exchange’s [Code of Conduct](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/conduct) still applies - so if it would be unacceptable to post normally, it’s unacceptable here.

Also, try to avoid pictures that include spoilers. We want everyone to be able to enjoy this contest, so the less spoilers the better.

#### How long will the contest run?

We will accept submissions for a week, until 19:00 UTC of 2023-06-05, then have a second week-long period where only voting will be accepted. This is to give every submission, even those posted at the end of the first week, a chance to be voted on by everyone.

After the end of the second week, at 19:00 UTC of 2023-06-12, we will count upvotes only to determine the winning screenshot, which will be featured for a week on the main site's photo widget.

---

## No Theme

There is no theme this week.

As a reminder, we're always accepting suggestions for themed weeks, and have compiled that suggestion process into a [question of its own](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15029/screenshot-of-the-week-themes).  Additionally, there is the [hall of fame](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14939/screenshot-of-the-week-hall-of-fame) you can check out that contains all the previous contest winners.

Comment: Can anyone post the next Screenshot of the Week question? Also, shouldn't the next one be available now?

Comment: According to [this](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16745/screenshot-of-the-week-88-easter-eggs#comment49108_16745) and [this](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16650/screenshot-of-the-week-82?rq=1#comment48961_16650) - YES. Go for it! When you post the question, I'll provide the first answer.

Comment: @User23415 mods are on strike, so no surprise nobody is updating the contest

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Picking up incoherent monologues and strange sights in ben lunato's [harts-island](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/harts-island):

[image]

Comment: Really interesting art style! Is that an individual image from a stop-motion cutscene or so or is that actually how the game looks, animated in 3D and yet looking like a line drawing?

Comment: @FabianRöling That's actually how the game looks, animated and all :)

Answer (score 12):

Giant rubber duck getting towed by a tow boat in [american-truck-simulator](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/american-truck-simulator).

I have *no idea* where I saw this, some sort of "easter egg" in American <strike>Duck</strike> Truck Simulator. Was just doing some haul past a bridge, absently glanced to the right and managed to catch a wtf screenie.

[image]

Comment: Yeah, that was not the game I expected..

Comment: (I _think_ this was somewhere in California, possibly around San Diego. Don't take my word for it though.)

Answer (score 9):

[image]

A nice peaceful night in [zelda-tears-of-the-kingdom](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/zelda-tears-of-the-kingdom)

Comment: You have a funny definition for "*a nice peaceful night*"

Comment: More a nightmare 

Comment: Is this Zelda game good.? I haven't play this game line for a while.

Comment: @nobody It's really good, I can recommend picking up Breath of the Wild as well

Comment: @Riley thank you

Comment: @Batophobia If you tap the bow button in midair instead of holding it in, it enters bullet time without taking up a ton of stamina. You can use this method for some really spectacular screenshots, like the one I plan to post next week.

Answer (score 8):

[image: Master sword fireworks]

Master Sword fireworks! [hyrule-warriors-age-of-calamity](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hyrule-warriors-age-of-calamity)

Answer (score 5):

The ritual of dundrasil in [dragon-quest-11](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dragon-quest-11)

[image: lost soul guide]

Answer (score 4):

The pretty colors of some of the materials needed to make Production Science Packs in [factorio](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/factorio):

[image: Pretty colors of [tag:factorio]]

Comment: Blood and grass, obviously.

Comment: [Steel plates](https://wiki.factorio.com/Steel_plate), [advanced circuits](https://wiki.factorio.com/Advanced_circuit), [electronic circuits](https://wiki.factorio.com/Electronic_circuit), [copper cable](https://wiki.factorio.com/Copper_cable), [copper plates](https://wiki.factorio.com/Copper_plate), [plastic](https://wiki.factorio.com/Plastic_bar), [productivity modules](https://wiki.factorio.com/Productivity_module), [electric furnaces](https://wiki.factorio.com/Electric_furnace) and [stone bricks](https://wiki.factorio.com/Stone_brick) is what you see!

Comment: I was slightly off.

Comment: Spaghetti is delicious.

Comment: In addition to blood and grass, I also see rice...

Answer (score 3):

As nicely polished and clean as this game has become, it is not without a few rather visible faults.
*(from one of the main menus in [microsoft-flight-simulator](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/microsoft-flight-simulator))*

[image]

Comment: That's quite harmless compared to some of the crazy issues seen here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NVNAkdaQCpY

Comment: Wow. That was the best 5 minutes of my morning. *("So, I'm in a jeep right now...")*

Answer (score 3):

[image: Olivier and the SSS in Trails to Azure]

One doesn't need Estelle to threaten Olivier with ul-tra-vi-o-lence in [trails-to-azure](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/trails-to-azure)