# Screenshot of the Week #93

Tags: discussion, community-event, screenshot-of-the-week

## The contest is over!

*[previous contest](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/16777) | [next contest](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/16817)*

---

Hello and welcome to the **93<sup>rd</sup>** edition of the Screenshot of the Week!

To start with, congratulations to the winner of the previous contest! [A Striking Joachim's](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/16781/87579) picture from [harts-island](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/harts-island) won with 13 upvotes!

[image: Last week's winning screenshot one]

---

To submit a screenshot, simply post it as an answer to this question, but please take note of the following:

- One screenshot per post, and one post per person, please!
- Limited picture modifications are allowed, such as cropping, simple filters, and blurring of identifying info such as names, but not adding other images or text.
- To ensure a fair playing field, please post screenshots you've taken yourself rather than ones you found online.
- Stack Exchange’s [Code of Conduct](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/conduct) still applies - so if it would be unacceptable to post normally, it’s unacceptable here.

Also, try to avoid pictures that include spoilers. We want everyone to be able to enjoy this contest, so the less spoilers the better.

#### How long will the contest run?

We will accept submissions for a week, until 19:00 UTC of 2023-06-19, then have a second week-long period where only voting will be accepted. This is to give every submission, even those posted at the end of the first week, a chance to be voted on by everyone.

After the end of the second week, at 19:00 UTC of 2023-06-26, we will count upvotes only to determine the winning screenshot, which will be featured for a week on the main site's photo widget.

---

## No Theme

There is no theme this week.

As a reminder, we're always accepting suggestions for themed weeks, and have compiled that suggestion process into a [question of its own](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15029/screenshot-of-the-week-themes).  Additionally, there is the [hall of fame](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14939/screenshot-of-the-week-hall-of-fame) you can check out that contains all the previous contest winners.

Comment: Thanks for posting this!

Comment: @Wipqozn no worries, I respect your strike and community's traditions too

Comment: I've added the featured tag here. Mods are still striking, we're still not responding to flags and staying out of review queues for the time being, but SotW is a community initiative, and thus (IMO) - the mod strike shouldn't negatively affect that. We still love our community :)

Comment: @Robotnik That is appreciated and seems fair :)

Comment: Suggestion for next week's theme: [Weapon Customizations](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/16475/163757).  I'd probably just say "weapons" in general as the theme.

Comment: Why that one specifically? "Photorealism" has 10 upvotes, "Explosions" 9, "Shiny things" 8, many suggestions have 7 to 3 upvotes, but "Weapon customisation" has only 2.

Comment: @FabianRöling just a suggestion.  I thought explosions actually had a post before, but I think I am remembering "[Destruction](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15905/screenshot-of-the-week-contest-42-destruction)" which featured a lot of explosions.  Photorealism I figured would be difficult for users to submit an "on-topic" answer to, since it by default excludes a lot of games that otherwise don't have stellar graphics.  I thought weapon customization/weapons would include a lot of games.

Comment: I'm pretty sure I've never played any game where you could customise weapons, except enchanting them in Minecraft, which always looks the same.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The first full view of the locomotive *Aurora* in [metro-exodus](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/metro-exodus)

[image]

Answer (score 9):

[image]

Starfield hype has me returning to Tamriel in [the-elder-scrolls-online](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-elder-scrolls-online)

Answer (score 6):

Final fantasy sure has come a long way in its newest title [final-fantasy-16](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/final-fantasy-16) (open demo)

[image]

Answer (score 4):

[image]

Nights can be beautiful in [zelda-tears-of-the-kingdom](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/zelda-tears-of-the-kingdom)

Answer (score 2):

The notice to 'please wait here' was ignored. Also, the queue post was broken, along with the laws of physics. Or maybe this hovering tether is just cursed, like everything else in the game.

[image]

All this within my first five minutes inside of [control](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/control)

Comment: It isn't exactly clear what object you're talking about.

Comment: @User23415 There's a rope hanging in midair, because a second pole is missing.

Comment: How could you knock down Ahti's queue post

Comment: I'M SO SORRY. IT WAS AN ACCIDENT.