# Screenshot of the Week #94 - Weapon customization

Tags: discussion, community-event, screenshot-of-the-week

## This contest is over.

*[previous contest](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/16797) | [next contest](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/16827)*

---

Hello and welcome to the **94<sup>th</sup>** edition of the Screenshot of the Week!

To start with, congratulations to the winner of the previous contest! [A Striking Joachim's](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/16806/87579) picture from [metro-exodus](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/metro-exodus) won with 10 upvotes!

[image: Last week's winning screenshot one]

---

To submit a screenshot, simply post it as an answer to this question, but please take note of the following:

- One screenshot per post, and one post per person, please!
- Limited picture modifications are allowed, such as cropping, simple filters, and blurring of identifying info such as names, but not adding other images or text.
- To ensure a fair playing field, please post screenshots you've taken yourself rather than ones you found online.
- Stack Exchange’s [Code of Conduct](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/conduct) still applies - so if it would be unacceptable to post normally, it’s unacceptable here.

Also, try to avoid pictures that include spoilers. We want everyone to be able to enjoy this contest, so the less spoilers the better.

#### How long will the contest run?

We will accept submissions for a week, until 19:00 UTC of 2023-07-03, then have a second week-long period where only voting will be accepted. This is to give every submission, even those posted at the end of the first week, a chance to be voted on by everyone.

After the end of the second week, at 19:00 UTC of 2023-07-10, we will count upvotes only to determine the winning screenshot, which will be featured for two weeks on the main site's photo widget.

---

## Weapon customization!

Do trick out your sword to burn your foes with blue flames on a hit, or have you somehow managed to fit five different scopes on your gun, or perhaps you've decided to use a tool that isn't really supposed to be a weapon in the first place?

This'll be the week to share it!

As a reminder, we're always accepting suggestions for themed weeks, and have compiled that suggestion process into a [question of its own](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15029/screenshot-of-the-week-themes).  Additionally, there is the [hall of fame](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14939/screenshot-of-the-week-hall-of-fame) you can check out that contains all the previous contest winners.

Comment: Time for me to figure out which of my TF2 weapons has the [longest name](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/225884/28182)

Comment: "the winning screenshot will be featured for a week on the main site's photo widget" we copy the whole body every time but I've just realized this is wrong, the winning photo is showcased for 2 weeks.

Comment: We should still stick with the name "screenshot of the week" instead of changing it to something awkward like "screenshot of the fortnight"

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Shields need more plush seals [zelda-tears-of-the-kingdom](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/zelda-tears-of-the-kingdom)

[image]

Comment: Fuse is the ultimate weapon customization tool. I'm glad someone used it.

Comment: @User23415 I have the habit of attempting to fuse everything, which ends up with some incredibly silly equipment.

Comment: Bouncy Shields automatically disarm enemies on a parry re*guard*less of the shield level, so you chose a solid fuse for your Sea-Breeze Shield.

Answer (score 9):

My Prowler SMG in [apex-legends](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/apex-legends) with "The Dark Realm" skin:

[image: Prowler SMG]