# Screenshot of the Week #95 - Shiny things!

Tags: discussion, community-event, screenshot-of-the-week

## This contest has ended.

*[previous contest](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/16817) | [next contest](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16833/screenshot-of-the-week-96)*

---

Hello and welcome to the **95<sup>th</sup>** edition of the Screenshot of the Week!

To start with, congratulations to the winner of the previous contest! [Batophobia's](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/16819/87579) picture from [zelda-tears-of-the-kingdom](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/zelda-tears-of-the-kingdom) won with 9 upvotes!

[image: Last week's winning screenshot one]

---

To submit a screenshot, simply post it as an answer to this question, but please take note of the following:

- One screenshot per post, and one post per person, please!
- Limited picture modifications are allowed, such as cropping, simple filters, and blurring of identifying info such as names, but not adding other images or text.
- To ensure a fair playing field, please post screenshots you've taken yourself rather than ones you found online.
- Stack Exchange’s [Code of Conduct](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/conduct) still applies - so if it would be unacceptable to post normally, it’s unacceptable here.

Also, try to avoid pictures that include spoilers. We want everyone to be able to enjoy this contest, so the less spoilers the better.

#### How long will the contest run?

We will accept submissions for a week, until 19:00 UTC of 2023-07-17, then have a second week-long period where only voting will be accepted. This is to give every submission, even those posted at the end of the first week, a chance to be voted on by everyone.

After the end of the second week, at 19:00 UTC of 2023-07-24, we will count upvotes only to determine the winning screenshot, which will be featured for a week on the main site's photo widget.

---

## Shiny things!

Do you love stuff that glows, glitters, and sparkles, and that a Magpie would like to steal?

This'll be the week to share it!

As a reminder, we're always accepting suggestions for themed weeks, and have compiled that suggestion process into a [question of its own](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15029/screenshot-of-the-week-themes).  Additionally, there is the [hall of fame](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14939/screenshot-of-the-week-hall-of-fame) you can check out that contains all the previous contest winners.

Comment: I'm considering posting [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wppvp.jpg) of the master sword, but I'm not sure whether this would be allowed.

Comment: @User23415 I don't think it's a problem itself, but it's kinda "spoilery"

Comment: That was the problem I was worried about.

Comment: The sidebar on the main site hasn't been updated, maybe Batophobia will only get a week for #94!

Comment: @GammaGames we need a mod for that

Comment: I'll accept the sidebar as a casualty of the strike 

Comment: We will survive that.

Comment: @User23415 It's completely fine to post, you can just put the screenshot in spoiler tags :)

Comment: Coming next week: [The fearsome electric chuchu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qQ6BF.jpg)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

So many shinies on the beach in [sea-of-thieves](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sea-of-thieves)

[image: Shiny!]

Comment: How long did it take to get all these?

Answer (score 8):

<del>Raiding</del> Visiting the tomb of Khufu in [assassins-creed-origins](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/assassins-creed-origins)

[image]

As an NPC from [baldurs-gate-2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/baldurs-gate-2) put it:

> "*Many, many pretties... piled high beyond the sky*".

Answer (score 6):

[image]
Blupee: Pictured from [zelda-tears-of-the-kingdom](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/zelda-tears-of-the-kingdom)

Answer (score 4):

Glow, glitter and spark sounds like this trailer one got to haul during the previous x-mas event in [american-truck-simulator](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/american-truck-simulator).

(Winter mod + real companies mods active.)

[image]

Answer (score 4):

We infiltrate the gnome's domain through the spirit vein. [trails-of-cold-steel-4](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/trails-of-cold-steel-4)

[image: saving rean]