# Screenshot of the Week #96

Tags: discussion, community-event, screenshot-of-the-week

## This contest is over.

*[previous contest](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/16827) | [next contest](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/16865)*

---

Hello and welcome to the **96<sup>th</sup>** edition of the Screenshot of the Week!

To start with, congratulations to the winner of the previous contest! [SaintWacko's](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/16828/163757) picture from [sea-of-thieves](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sea-of-thieves) won with 9 upvotes!

[image: Last week's winning screenshot one]

---

To submit a screenshot, simply post it as an answer to this question, but please take note of the following:

- One screenshot per post, and one post per person, please!
- Limited picture modifications are allowed, such as cropping, simple filters, and blurring of identifying info such as names, but not adding other images or text.
- To ensure a fair playing field, please post screenshots you've taken yourself rather than ones you found online.
- Stack Exchange’s [Code of Conduct](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/conduct) still applies - so if it would be unacceptable to post normally, it’s unacceptable here.

Also, try to avoid pictures that include spoilers. We want everyone to be able to enjoy this contest, so the less spoilers the better.

#### How long will the contest run?

We will accept submissions for a week, until 19:00 UTC of 2023-07-31, then have a second week-long period where only voting will be accepted. This is to give every submission, even those posted at the end of the first week, a chance to be voted on by everyone.

After the end of the second week, at 19:00 UTC of 2023-08-07, we will count upvotes only to determine the winning screenshot, which will be featured for a week on the main site's photo widget.

---

## No Theme

There is no theme this week.

As a reminder, we're always accepting suggestions for themed weeks, and have compiled that suggestion process into a [question of its own](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15029/screenshot-of-the-week-themes).  Additionally, there is the [hall of fame](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14939/screenshot-of-the-week-hall-of-fame) you can check out that contains all the previous contest winners.

Comment: First entry, first upvote, first view.

Comment: Is the strike over?

Comment: @pinckerman we still do SOTW.  We usually just forget or someone beats us to it. :)

Answer (score 10):

[image]

Preparing to enter the ruins in [kena-bridge-of-spirits](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kena-bridge-of-spirits).

Answer (score 7):

A glittery night sky in [final-fantasy-16](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/final-fantasy-16)

[image: A glittery night sky]

Answer (score 4):

[image]

A trippy portion of Tartarus in [persona-3-portable](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/persona-3-portable).

Answer (score 3):

[image]
The fearsome Electric Chuchu in [zelda-tears-of-the-kingdom](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/zelda-tears-of-the-kingdom)

Answer (score 3):

The safari jeep ride lets visitors come really close to the animals in [planet-zoo](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/planet-zoo).

[image]

Answer (score 1):

[image]

---

[assassins-creed-odyssey](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/assassins-creed-odyssey)

Comment: What exactly is this?

Comment: Too blurry.....

Comment: There is no need for it to be anything, a screenshot is a screenshot :) (And I guess it's a landscape, or seascape, with a setting sun.)

Comment: @AstrikingJoachim true, but I'm mainly curious. I guess it's the sky at dusk