# Screenshot of the Week #98

Tags: discussion, community-event, screenshot-of-the-week

## This contest is over.

*[previous contest](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/16865) | [next contest](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/16884)*

---

Hello and welcome to the **98<sup>th</sup>** edition of the Screenshot of the Week!

To start with, congratulations to the winner of the previous contest! [Artfaith](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/16870/87579)'s picture from [mirrors-edge-catalyst](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mirrors-edge-catalyst) won with 12 upvotes!

[image: Last week's winning screenshot one]

---

To submit a screenshot, simply post it as an answer to this question, but please take note of the following:

- One screenshot per post, and one post per person, please!
- Limited picture modifications are allowed, such as cropping, simple filters, and blurring of identifying info such as names, but not adding other images or text.
- To ensure a fair playing field, please post screenshots you've taken yourself rather than ones you found online.
- Stack Exchange’s [Code of Conduct](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/conduct) still applies - so if it would be unacceptable to post normally, it’s unacceptable here.

Also, try to avoid pictures that include spoilers. We want everyone to be able to enjoy this contest, so the less spoilers the better.

#### How long will the contest run?

We will accept submissions for a week, until 19:00 UTC of 2023-09-11, then have a second week-long period where only voting will be accepted. This is to give every submission, even those posted at the end of the first week, a chance to be voted on by everyone.

After the end of the second week, at 19:00 UTC of 2023-09-18, we will count upvotes only to determine the winning screenshot, which will be featured for a week on the main site's photo widget.

---

## No Theme

There is no theme this week.

As a reminder, we're always accepting suggestions for themed weeks, and have compiled that suggestion process into a [question of its own](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15029/screenshot-of-the-week-themes).  Additionally, there is the [hall of fame](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14939/screenshot-of-the-week-hall-of-fame) you can check out that contains all the previous contest winners.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Looking towards the Decrepit Village in the Underdark in [baldurs-gate-3](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/baldurs-gate-3).

[image]

Comment: Hint: Make sure to bring a friendly mushroom-man called Glut and his resurrected Bulette monster pet! Then you can moonwalk through this area.

Comment: (Btw the Arcane Tower nearby in the Underdark is probably a nice screen shot-worthy location too.)

Comment: @Amarth Definitely! After my current playthrough I'll install a free camera mod (I don't want to mess with achievements currently) and do a lot more elaborate screen archery :) And unfortunately I had already done everything in the Underdark when I found out about Glut.

Comment: Yep I didn't use him either on my first play-through. Entirely optional but he can revive pretty much any dead creature in that whole map, including the mentioned Bulette which is really fun to bring along with its jump ability, although it is pretty big. The duergar were going to ambush me... well I ambushed them by dropping a metric ton undead mushroom lizard on them! :D (Almost as epic as when I used telekinesis spell to throw a live ogre from on top of a tower down onto a hostile gang below during the final battles :))

Answer (score 10):

[image]

[moons-of-madness](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/moons-of-madness), while not the best game to play, was certainly very pretty to look at.

Answer (score 10):

Enjoying the sunset on the sea [horizon-forbidden-west](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/horizon-forbidden-west)

[image]

Answer (score 9):

Kratos casts an upvote in [god-of-war-ragnarok](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/god-of-war-ragnarok)

[image]

Comment: Nice try 

Comment: An upvote for an upvote

Comment: (It's actually a real Norse rune from the Elder Futhark, basically an 'L' and supposedly it could symbolize water also.)

Answer (score 8):

Onward to adventure! [pikmin-4](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pikmin-4)

[image]

Answer (score 7):

"The eagles are coming! The eagles are com-..." *SPLAT!*

At the top of Rosymorn Monastery in [baldurs-gate-3](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/baldurs-gate-3).

[image: eagles]

Comment: I thought "*I'm not going to kill these majestic creatures, especially not over a ceremonial mace*". Then my main character accidentally stepped on the mother's nest, and.. ..yeah, SPLAT! (That dialogue and voice acting, though, XD)

Comment: @Joachim I had a speak with animals potion this playthrough and after speaking with mommy eagle I decided that the above documented fate was appropriate for her :)

Comment: Yikes! I'll try to keep you on my good side, then :) (It was good to have the Ceremonial Mace after all, though. For a nice Legendary item :)

Comment: @Joachim My first playthrough I found the chamber with the insignia thing is kept and Astarion just moonwalked through a lockpick roll - no need for ceremonial weapons then. But it's a 30 or something ridiculously high.

Comment: Ah, I didn't even check :)

Answer (score 3):

2 possible outcommings after the event in the gral.

2 different reans's. [trails-into-reverie](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/trails-into-reverie)

[image: which of them is the real deal]

Answer (score 2):

[image: Anton in The Legend of Heroes: Trails of Cold Steel]

Anton in [trails-of-cold-steel](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/trails-of-cold-steel) after Fran Seeker broke his heart (for the third time) during *Trails from Zero*

Comment: Poor Anton first Fran than Sharon 