# Screenshot of the Week #99

Tags: discussion, community-event, screenshot-of-the-week

## This contest is over.

*[previous contest](//meta.arqade.com/q/16872/) | [next contest](//meta.arqade.com/q/16898/)*

---

Hello and welcome to the **99<sup>th</sup>** edition of the Screenshot of the Week!

To start with, congratulations to the winner of the previous contest! [Joachim](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/16874/87579)'s picture from [baldurs-gate-3](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/baldurs-gate-3) won with 15 upvotes!

[image: Last week's winning screenshot one]

---

To submit a screenshot, simply post it as an answer to this question, but please take note of the following:

- One screenshot per post, and one post per person, please!
- Limited picture modifications are allowed, such as cropping, simple filters, and blurring of identifying info such as names, but not adding other images or text.
- To ensure a fair playing field, please post screenshots you've taken yourself rather than ones you found online.
- Stack Exchange’s [Code of Conduct](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/conduct) still applies - so if it would be unacceptable to post normally, it’s unacceptable here.

Also, try to avoid pictures that include spoilers. We want everyone to be able to enjoy this contest, so the less spoilers the better.

#### How long will the contest run?

We will accept submissions for a week, until 19:00 UTC of 2023-09-25, then have a second week-long period where only voting will be accepted. This is to give every submission, even those posted at the end of the first week, a chance to be voted on by everyone.

After the end of the second week, at 19:00 UTC of 2023-10-02, we will count upvotes only to determine the winning screenshot, which will be featured for a week on the main site's photo widget.

---

## No Theme

There is no theme this week.

As a reminder, we're always accepting suggestions for themed weeks, and have compiled that suggestion process into a [question of its own](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15029/screenshot-of-the-week-themes).  Additionally, there is the [hall of fame](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14939/screenshot-of-the-week-hall-of-fame) you can check out that contains all the previous contest winners.

Comment: Please also think of something special to do for our 100th Screenshot of the Week which is due up next!!! Us mods were thinking of doing something a little different to commemorate this on going event.

Comment: @TimmyJim yeah don't worry, I'll let you post for the 100th contest :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The late sunlight of dusk throwing autumnal colours on the floors of the ruins of Rosymorn Monastery, once dedicated to Lathander, currently a distracting entrance to the crèche Y'llek:

[image]

[baldurs-gate-3](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/baldurs-gate-3)

Comment: Wow! Did you park yourself in that spot long to take this shot?

Comment: @LoreFriendly No, the game has no day/night cycle or similar changes in lighting. This is as-is. Obviously the developers paid a lot of attention to set the mood in the different environments, though, and the setting sun is appropriate for a location that used to be dedicated to the Morning Lord, the god of dawn, symbolized by the rising sun, but currently lies in ruins.

Answer (score 6):

No talking in the library [tunic](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tunic)

[image]

Comment: Finally, someone else who has played this game! For a exploration game that has so many puzzles and secret areas, it was a little surprising there are still 0 questions about it on the main site. I suppose there are plenty of other resources out there...

Answer (score 6):

[image: Sunrise with Yuna in Final Fantasy XIV]

Watching the morning Sunrise with Yuna untop of the Puzzle tower during the 2023 Moonfire Faire event in [final-fantasy-xiv](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/final-fantasy-xiv)

ignore Fran defying gravity there

Answer (score 4):

[image: grandia]
Taken from [grandia](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grandia) opening.