# Screenshot of the Week Themes

Tags: discussion, screenshot-of-the-week

To make is easier to track what themes have been suggested, this will be a central location for proposing themes for future Screenshot of the Week contests.

Please limit answers to one theme per answer to allow for voting on individual themes. For submission, please have a short summary like "Glitches and bugs", followed by a small summary.

Comment: Will answers be removed once the theme has been done?

Comment: @FabianRöling no, we will reuse themes in the future

Comment: I added a couple of non-suggested themes used in previous contest, just to keep track and maybe reuse them in the future

Answer (score 16):

Theme idea: **Secrets / Easter Eggs**

Show off your favorite things in games that reference other things!

---

**Theme featured in:**

1. [Screenshot of the Week Contest #32: Secrets and Easter Eggs](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/15569)
2. [Screenshot of the Week #88: Easter (Eggs)](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16745/screenshot-of-the-week-88-easter-eggs)

Answer (score 16):

Theme: **Epic Fail**

Show us your face-palming, gut wrenching, embarrassing epic moments of failure!

---

Used in SOTW 66:

- [Screenshot of the Week #66: Epic Fail!](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16441/screenshot-of-the-week-66-epic-fail)

Comment: I can't wait for this one lol

Answer (score 15):

Theme idea: **Moments before Disaster**

That split second before Murphy's law kicks in.

---

**Theme featured in:**

1. [Screenshot of the Week #11: Moments Before Disaster](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/15042/28182)

Answer (score 15):

Theme idea: Victory.

Win first place? Finish that impossible level? Conquer the world? Triumph and success, no matter how small, can be quite satisfying. Show off your victories.

---

**Theme featured in:**

1. [Screenshot of the Week Contest #17: Victory](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15204/screenshot-of-the-week-contest-17-victory)

Answer (score 13):

Theme idea: **Residence**.

Whether it be a humble abode, intimidating castle, ivory tower, or fortress of solitude: it's time to show off your hours of work.

---

**Theme featured in:**

1. [Screenshot of the Week #13: Residence](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/15111/28182)

Answer (score 13):

Theme Idea: **Hero Pose**

It could be you or an NPC, show a character striking a cool pose for the camera!

---

**Theme featured in:**

1. [Screenshot of the Week #52 - Hero Pose!](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/16148/28182)

Comment: Pretty similar to https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/15060/171580 .

Comment: @FabianRöling similar, but specifically about a character and not necessarily a victory, just a cool pose :-)

Answer (score 12):

Theme idea: **Glitches and Bugs**

Any weird/fun glitches or bugs that you experience while playing.

---

**Theme featured in:**

1. [Screenshot of the week contest #5: Glitches and Bugs](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/14863/28182)
2. [Screenshot of the Week #109 - Glitches and Bugs](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/17026/screenshot-of-the-week-109-glitches-and-bugs)

Answer (score 12):

Theme idea: Loading Screens.

Everyone hates to have loading screens, but some are quite interesting or hilarious. Show us the best you've found.

---

**Theme featured in:**

1. [Screenshot of the Week Contest #26: Loading Screens](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/15412)

Answer (score 12):

Theme idea: 90s (1990-1999) - No HD Remasters

Get retro. Only 90's kids will remember these.

---

**Theme featured in:**

1. [Screenshot of the Week Contest #15: '90s](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/15164/28182)

Answer (score 12):

Theme idea: Achievements!

Show off your hard work in a game.

Your promotion in a competitive game. You standing victorious over that one Boss. You dinging to max-level.

---

**Theme featured in:**

- [Screenshot of the Week #91 - Achievements!](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16773/screenshot-of-the-week-91-achievements)

Comment: I'd argue that this was featured in [#17: Victory](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15204/screenshot-of-the-week-contest-17-victory) but we'll talk through it for the next themed week since we're already very late this week

Comment: I was about to add this theme to the current SotW, but first we have to discuss how to properly take screenshots of achievements. Do we count mentions? I know some games automatically take screenshots when an achievement is made, but the lion's share does not.

Answer (score 12):

Theme idea: Halloween.

Ghosts, pumpkins, monsters, demons, witches, and spooky stuff. Whatever your traditions are, show off something that represents Halloween.

---

**Theme featured in:**

1. [Screenshot of the Week Contest #24: Halloween](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/15375/171580)
2. [Screenshot of Week #50 - Halloween](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/16120/163757)
3. [Screenshot of the Week #76 - Halloween](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/16558)
4. [Screenshot of the Week #102 - Halloween](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/16933)

Answer (score 12):

Theme idea: Classic.

All submissions must come from a game 10 years old or older.

---

**Theme featured in:**

1. [Screenshot of the Week Contest #21: Classic Games](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/15308)

Comment: How would this work with games that have been receiving continuous updates for 10 years? Minecraft and World of Warcraft both have been receiving updates regularly. Also, there fairly little difference with the 90s theme, just slightly more encompassing.

Comment: @Nzall I would suggest the main focus of the submission would need to be from content that existed from the game as it was at least 10 years ago.

Comment: What about games that were released 10 years ago, but the content is TOTALLY different? Or mostly different? MMORPGs aren't known for keeping old content around. Tera, for example, closed a lot of old dungeons.

Answer (score 12):

Theme idea: Love Declaration. (for a Valentine's Day week?)

Either between characters or from a character to an inanimate object/concept, either funny or sad, there's a lot of ways one could declare their love.

---

**Theme featured in:**

- [Screenshot of the Week #84 - Love Declaration/Valentines](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16681/screenshot-of-the-week-84-love-declaration-valentines)

Comment: It'd usually seem a bit meh, but there was just a only-fans-will-get-it moment like this in the game I'm currently playing, so... why not :)

Comment: Could be simplified to Love

Answer (score 12):

Theme Idea: Living with Nature

Screenshots of you working with nature/the environment, from buildings to befriending animals to using nature to defeat your foe

---

**Theme featured in:**

1. [Screenshot of the Week #72 - Living with Nature](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16508/screenshot-of-the-week-72-living-with-nature)

Answer (score 12):

Theme idea: Explosions

Make something go *boom!* The bigger, the better.

---

**Theme featured in:**

1. [Screenshot of the Week #104 - Explosions!](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16962/screenshot-of-the-week-104-explosions)

Answer (score 11):

Theme idea: Winter.

Winter is coming! Show us your frigid adventure, or cozy home you are holing up in to wait it out.

---

**Theme featured in:**

1. [Screenshot of the Week contest #34: Winter](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/15641)

Answer (score 11):

Theme idea: RNG!

Do the RNGods favor you? Show us your (un)luckiest moments.

That ultra rare drop you were lucky to get. Absurd moments caused by the world generator.
You dying to that rare triple crit by the basic enemy.

---

**Theme featured in:**

1. [Screenshot of the Week Contest #44 - RNG](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15962/screenshot-of-the-week-contest-44-rng)

Answer (score 11):

Theme idea: Water scenes.

On the water, under water, ocean views. Scenes with water as a major part of the composition.

---

**Theme featured in:**

1. [Screenshot of the Week Contest #23: Water Scenes](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/15342/171580)

Answer (score 11):

Theme idea: **Photorealism**

Screenshots that are impossible to distinguish from IRL photographs.

Answer (score 10):

Theme idea: Space Exploration.

Take us to where no person has gone before. What are you coolest finds out in space?

---

**Theme featured in:**

1. [Screenshot of the Week Contest #19: Space Exploration](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/15260)

Answer (score 10):

Theme idea: Robots/Synths/AIs

Show your appreciation for your robot overlords.

---

**Theme featured in:**

1. [Screenshot of the Week Contest #40: Robots!](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15851/screenshot-of-the-week-contest-40)

Answer (score 10):

Theme idea: Inventory

Immense stacks of potions, a pet, a fancy hat, trivial trinkets, mountains of gold, that one *weapon-that-will-be-extremely-useful-in-that-very-particular-situation*: show us what you got!

---

**Theme Featured in**: [Screenshot of the Week #74 - Inventory](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16529/screenshot-of-the-week-74-inventory?cb=1)

Answer (score 10):

Recurring Theme Idea: Game of the Year

Show off something from your favorite game from the past year.  This could be an annual theme that happens every December or January, maybe coinciding with the Winterbash?

---

**Theme Featured in:**

1. [Screenshot of the Week Contest #30: Game of the Year 2020](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/15511/163757)

Answer (score 10):

Theme idea: Destruction!

Images of the highest level of carnage, debris, or otherwise broken and explodey stuff.

---

**Theme featured in:**

1. [Screenshot of the Week Contest #42: Destruction!](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15905/screenshot-of-the-week-contest-42-destruction)

Answer (score 10):

Theme idea: Christmas

Just thinking ahead :)

Also: snowy landscapes, guiding stars, comfy carols, pagan ceremonies, useless gifts, trees with lights in them, krampuses, turońs, zwarte pieten, and other figures that perpetuate misopedic, sexist, and racist traditions. Merry Christmas!

---

**Theme Featured in:**

1. [Screenshot of the Week Contest #28: Holiday](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/15474/163757)
2. [Screenshot of the Week Contest #54: Happy Holidays 2021!](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/16171/28182)
3. [Screenshot of the Week #80 - Happy Holidays 2022!](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/16623/)
4. [Screenshot of the Week #105 - Happy Holidays 2023!](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/16973/)

Comment: It's been 3 years since this was posted and I've edited it multiple times, and I am just now realizing the last few items in the paragraph... uhhhhhhhhh

Comment: @TimmyJim Yeah, the history of many contemporary holidays is quite loaded. And what a well-chosen platform to bring that up, right?

Comment: I knew what you were going for, I just totally missed it

Comment: @TimmyJim Understandable, given the circumstances :)

Answer (score 10):

Theme idea: Night

What makes you afraid of the dark? Does something lurk in the shadows?

Is it a peaceful, starry night? Does the night sky shimmer with dancing lights?

Scenes taken at night.

1. [Screenshot of the Week #48 - Nighttime](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16092/screenshot-of-the-week-48-nighttime)

Answer (score 9):

Theme idea: **Scenery**

For sharing all the picturesque, hidden, or otherwise interesting locations or objects.

---

**Theme featured in:**

1. [Screenshot of the Week Contest #8: Scenery](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/14966/28182)

Answer (score 9):

Theme idea: Giant monsters.

I already have a good one for this category, I want to share it. ;)

---

**Theme featured in:**

1. [Screenshot of the Week Contest #36: Giant Monsters](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15718/screenshot-of-the-week-contest-36-giant-monsters)

Answer (score 9):

Theme Idea: Pets

Whether it's something traditional, like a dog or cat, or fantastical, like a chocobo or tiny dragon.

---

Theme featured in:

1. [Screenshot of the Week #58 - Pets](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16245/screenshot-of-the-week-58-pets)

Answer (score 8):

Theme idea: Shiny things!

Stuff that glows, glitters, and sparkles, and that a Magpie would like to steal.

---

**Theme Featured in:**

1. [Screenshot of the Week #95 - Shiny things!](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16827/screenshot-of-the-week-95-shiny-things)

Answer (score 8):

Theme idea: Into the storm!

Rain, snow, sand, flower petals, arrows, or anything at all that could be considered a storm worthy to remember.

---

**Theme featured in:**

1. [Screenshot of the Week Contest #38: Into the Storm](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15804/screenshot-of-the-week-contest-38-into-the-storm)

Answer (score 8):

**Theme Idea:** Moments After Disaster

Similar to moments before disaster, but the immediate aftermath.

---

**Theme Featured in:**

- [Screenshot of the Week #60: Moments After Disaster](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16285/screenshot-of-the-week-60-moments-after-disaster)

Answer (score 8):

Theme Idea: **How Fashionable!**

Check out these duds! Showcase your character wearing their fanciest, funniest, rarest, coolest, grungiest -- whatever attire you'd like to show off.

---

**Them featured in:**

1. [Screenshot of the Week #86: How Fashionable!](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16707/screenshot-of-the-week-86-how-fashionable)

Answer (score 7):

Theme idea: **Wildlife**

Any cool, cute, creepy, terrifying, etc animals, monsters, and other assortments of wildlife.

---

**Theme featured in:**

1. [Screenshot of the week contest #6: Wildlife](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/14912/28182)

Answer (score 7):

Theme idea: Character Customization

Show us those amazing characters that you've spent hours/days creating.

---

**Theme Featured in:**

- [Screenshot of the Week #46: Character Customization!](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16054/screenshot-of-the-week-46-character-customization)

Comment: Physical appearance, or customized gear, weapons, etc.? Maybe split the two?

Comment: @Joachim those all fit. mostly thinking of decking your character out in cool gear and posting a picture of them. that can include customize gear, weapons, etc.

Comment: https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/avatar/images/8/84/Aang%27s_armor.png

Answer (score 7):

Theme idea: Modding/Mods

Mods add a whole new experience to games. Show us yours!

Answer (score 7):

Theme idea: Selfies

Just like in real life: your character face with something interesting on the background

---

**Theme featured in**:

- [Screenshot of the Week #107 - Selfie!](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16994/screenshot-of-the-week-107-selfie)

Comment: Watch dogs 2 had the selfie feature standing in front of SF landmarks in game.

Answer (score 7):

Theme Idea: **Constructive Buildings**

The best buildings or infrastructures you can find.

Comment: That you can find, or that you can build?

Answer (score 7):

Theme idea: **Heroic Women**

Any herioc-looking female character!

Answer (score 7):

Theme idea: **Cameo**

Any spotted appearance of a well-known person/character/sprite from another videogame (or universe).

Answer (score 7):

Theme idea: **Small but powerful**

A pint-sized character that packs a surprising punch.

---

**Theme featured in:**

1. [Screenshot of the Week #112 - Small but powerful](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17059/screenshot-of-the-week-112-small-but-powerful)

Answer (score 7):

Theme Idea: **Romance**

*Living in the sunlight, loving in the moonlight, having a wonderful time!*

Answer (score 7):

Theme idea: **Video Game Toilets**.

[As inspired by this recent viral question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/405206/what-was-the-first-game-to-show-toilets), we want to see the best toilets as featured in a video game.  This somehow seems like a worthwhile theme to try out for one of the weeks!

Comment: Hopefully we don't get a lot of ... crappy screenshots from this theme ;D

Answer (score 6):

Theme idea: **Reactions**

The kind of images you could use as a response to a situation

Comment: You want to start a breeding ground for memes?

Comment: @Joachim More like contain them to a single theme.

Answer (score 6):

Theme Idea: Conquering Nature

The [reverse of my previous idea](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/15415/30879), Screenshots of the devastation to nature for your own personal gain like how much of a forest you demolished for your village, how flattened a mountain got for you to get some ore.

Answer (score 6):

Theme: **Sweet Rides**

Show off your wheels (or other vehicles) in your favorite game!

---

**Theme Featured in**:

- [Screenshot of the Week #56 - Sweet Rides](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16210/screenshot-of-the-week-56-sweet-rides)

Answer (score 6):

Theme idea: **Game Over Screens**.

Similar to "Loading Screens", some are funny, some are sad, I'm sure there are hidden masterpieces out there.

Answer (score 6):

Theme idea: **Traitor**

From Sylvanas from World of Warcraft to Loki from Avengers, may the best back-stabbing character win this round!

Answer (score 6):

Theme Idea: **Favourite Companion**

This can be *any* companion; from loyal animal companions, an odd couple entwined eternal in an unpredictable world... to an android friend follower, equally invested in your shared escapades, giving ever-welcome bites of sage advice and backup muscle just when you really need it. ...and everything in between!

---

**Theme featured in:**

- [Screenshot of the Week #111 - Favourite Companion](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17045/screenshot-of-the-week-111)

Answer (score 6):

Theme: **I got your back**

The main character often gets all the attention, but let's look at moments when a side character gets their "[15-minutes-of-fame](https://www.yourdictionary.com/15-minutes-of-fame)"

Answer (score 6):

Theme: Going Fast!

Screenshots of really fast things!

Answer (score 5):

Theme idea: **Physics**

The joy of ragdolls, completely destructible environments, rigid/soft bodies, real-time simulated particles, ballistics, aerodynamics, &c.

Answer (score 5):

Theme Idea: **Difficult decisions**

Games often ask us to make hard and meaningful choices. Let's collect the moments in gaming which had us put down the controller and think hard about what's the right course of action.

Answer (score 5):

Theme Idea **Weapon Customization**

Do trick out your sword to burn your foes with blue flames on a hit, or have you somehow managed to [fit five different scopes on your gun](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wqX5b.png), or perhaps you've decided to use a tool that [isn't really supposed to be a weapon in the first place](https://i.ytimg.com/vi/O_2f8wFa7rk/maxresdefault.jpg).

This'll be the week to share it

---

**Theme Featured in**:

1. [Screenshot of the Week #94 - Weapon customization](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16817/screenshot-of-the-week-94-weapon-customization)

Comment: Tarkov be like: "Yo Dawg, I heard you like sniper scopes, so we put a sniper scope in your sniper scope, so you can snipe while you snipe"

Answer (score 4):

Theme idea: UI

Another semi-fixed option, but (well-designed / beautiful / hopelessly complex / terrible) UIs need a little love too, every now and then.

Answer (score 4):

Theme Idea: **Out of Context**

Let's face it, video game characters are notorious for doing outrageous things in the heat of the moment. The context given during gameplay *typically* makes their actions appropriate or at the very least, justified. But, sometimes, when these situations are viewed out of context, they become questionable in many different ways. Sometimes games will even remove context from a situation on purpose, just for the sake of entertainment. Regardless of the situation, the perception is generally the same to a wide audience. Some situations are taken in a spicy manner:

> Don't touch me, I'm sterile. - Patrick Star

While others make you question what was happening entirely:

[image: Screenshot of Michael Stevens' head in a box.]

Show us something in your game that made you or someone else question the situation due to a lack of context. As always, the code of conduct should be followed, so keep the imagery clean!

Comment: This is a long-winded description for an idea I still don't really understand. Can you clarify it? I also really don't see the relevance of the image. Or maybe just leave it at 'Out of Context' and see how users interpret it?

Comment: Any picture that it makes perfect sense in the middle of the game, but for someone to see it out of context, it would be very weird.

Answer (score 4):

Theme idea: **(Good) Jokes**

Simple, yet easily found almost everywhere - jokes in games. Be it obscure references, awkward ones or something else - share the jokes you can find with us!

Answer (score 4):

Theme idea: **Bosses**

Submit a screenshot of a boss character from a video game.

Examples:

- Bowser (Super Mario)
- The Ender Dragon (Minecraft)
- Ganondorf (The Legend of Zelda)

---

Theme featured in:

- [Screenshot of the Week #62 - Bosses and Villains](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16320/screenshot-of-the-week-62-bosses-and-villains)

Answer (score 4):

Theme idea: Food

What delicious morsels exist in your game? Is it a mountain of meat? A world made of cake? Would you eat that meal if it was on your plate?

Answer (score 4):

Theme idea: **From father to son**

Screenshots of a younger generation taking on the roles of their elders

Answer (score 4):

**Minigames**

Screenshots from a minigame in a game you like and play.
Like, for example, Sphere Break in [final-fantasy-10-2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/final-fantasy-10-2)

Answer (score 4):

**Castles**

From the stone edifices of yore to neo-Gothic follies<sup>*</sup>, from magnificent pinnacles of architectural skill and ingenuity to the also magnificent battered ruins of time forgotten.

<sup>* Not particularly abundant in video games.</sup>

---

I realize I already proffered [Residence](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/15045/222022), but castles are so cool they deserve a dedicated theme.

Answer (score 3):

Theme: **Out of Doors (IRL)**

Show us your epic gaming moment (preferably an outdoor scene), that happens while you yourself and your gaming rig (of small or large proportions) are also out of doors!

Answer (score 3):

Theme idea: Alone.

Something on its own in a much larger setting - a player, a rock, a tower, whatever.

Answer (score 3):

**Theme: "Wait, that's illegal"**

Show us moments or things that feel illegal (in the context and scope of the game), but are completely legal

Answer (score 3):

frightening Allies.

Show the ally that makes you scared; even you know she/he is on your side.

Comment: Similar idea to this theme, "Strange Company" where the allies can be just wacky, odd, or otherwise out of place.

Answer (score 3):

Theme idea: **Out of bounds**

Anything cool or interesting that's placed outside the bonds of a map, or anything that requires you to go out of the bounds to see close or in better detail.

Comment: If only I still had my Xbox360 & Halo 3 :(

Comment: If you have the Halo DVD, you may be able to emulate it pretty decently. There's lots of out of bounds stuff in that game, and everything I've seen (so far) was interesting. (And no, I've never played it.)

Answer (score 3):

Theme idea: **Machines of War**

Show us your weaponized vehicles made to smash, burn, and otherwise destroy your opponents' stuff.

Answer (score 3):

Theme Idea: **Preinstalled Games**

You've just bought a new gaming device, or fresh installed your operating system. What games or demos were preinstalled? Which ones do you remember fondly (or not so fondly?)

Answer (score 3):

**Theme idea**: A still more glorious dawn awaits

Show your coolest sunrise/dawn screenshots.

Answer (score 2):

Theme idea: Colored Squares

Submissions must come from pixel-graphic games (8-bit and 16-bit).

Answer (score 2):

Theme idea: Exclusive

Share your favorite Mario, Halo, Ratchet & Clank, or any number of console-exclusive characters with some that may not know them!

Games must be exclusive to a single company's consoles, for example only on Sony PS3 and PS4.  Also acceptable are titles getting a later PC release, such as The Master Chief Collection.

Comment: I think this theme is along the same lines as series-specific themes (last discussion regarding this was in [SotW 12](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15079/screenshot-of-the-week-contest-12)). Restricting it to a specific console would limit who has the ability post a submission

Comment: @Wondercricket The exception here is that it's not restricted to one console, but rather any console that has a game unplayable to users without that console (plus PC versions of those games).  So anyone can contribute to this theme, regardless of their hardware.

Comment: @BoogaRoo It's not that the characters are restricted, but rather the specific game.  For example, [Cloud Strife](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cloud_Strife) can be seen outside PS hardware, but FF7 was exclusive to the first PlayStation and Smash Bros is exclusive to Nintendo, so those games all would work.

Comment: @BoogaRoo PC releases do not count against exclusivity for the purposes of this criteria.

Answer (score 2):

Theme: **Gaming Tatoos**, or **How do you rep gaming IRL?**

Show us how gaming shows up when you are not in front of the screen!

Comment: This is an interesting theme. I've been wanting to get a gaming tattoo for a good while now, but never did it. The idea would be getting a Pokeball for each of my kids

Comment: lol the idea came to me that I have my avatar (the sombrero guy) tatooed on my arm. But yeah I love the idea of a pokeball for each of your kids. The tatoo artist that made mine had as a personal objective to tatoo each of the OG 151 pokemon lol.

Comment: I always identified with sombrero guy since I saw it in Paper Mario because I am shy, but I don't mind when I need to put my party on.

Comment: Hope to see this in the future, I have one too!

Comment: Wait, can I screenshot my tattoos? lol

Answer (score 2):

Theme idea: **The Great Outdoors**

Submit a screenshot of an outdoor scene - anything that isn't indoors!
*From the TimmyJimtionary: "outdoors, adverb: anything that isn't indoors" ([credit](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16413/screenshot-of-the-week-64-the-great-outdoors))*

---

**Theme featured in:**

1. [Screenshot of the Week #64 - The Great Outdoors](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/16413/53249)

Answer (score 2):

Theme idea: **Relaxing**

Any location, scene or environment you felt was quiet, relaxing or enjoyable for your senses.

Answer (score 2):

Theme idea: **Is this for ants?**

Anything that's way smaller than necessary, clearly made for [Mr Chang](https://tenor.com/it/view/chang-paper-small-letters-gif-8177286).

Answer (score 2):

Theme idea: **Aerials**

Screenshots taken from midair or from flying vehicles.

Answer (score 2):

### Exploits

Show us your favourite exploit in the form of a screenshot!

Answer (score 2):

Theme: **Cute and Cuddly**

Any animal/creature really cute that made you say "Awww!"

Answer (score 2):

Theme: **Supernatural & Undead**

Some paranormal/supernatural/undead thing, like ghosts, zombies, ghouls, demons, or something "attributed to some force beyond scientific understanding or the laws of nature." (according to Google's definition).

---

**Theme featured in:**

1. [Screenshot of the Week #70 - Supernatural & Undead](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16484/screenshot-of-the-week-70-supernatural-undead)

Answer (score 1):

Show us your hero's determination.

Comment: How would one illustrate this? I'm just wondering what one could submit for this theme.

Comment: Like this https://ibb.co/WDqp120

Answer (score 1):

Theme: **Sheer Dominance**

Something where you dominated. Maybe you owned the enemy team with your 67-3 K/D ratio, beat someone's personal best record by an insane amount of time/points, or whatever you feel you were dominant at!

---

**Theme featured in:**

1. [Screenshot of the Week #68 - Sheer Dominance](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16456/screenshot-of-the-week-68-sheer-dominance)

Answer (score 1):

Theme idea: **Card battles**

Show us a cool screen from card game battle.