# Screenshot of the Week #49

Tags: discussion, community-event, screenshot-of-the-week

## This contest has ended

*[previous contest](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/16092) | [next contest](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/16120)*

---

Hello and welcome to the forty-ninth edition of the Screenshot of the Week!

To start with, congratulations to the winner of the previous contest! [pinckerman's submission](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/16095/8350) of them admiring the horizon of a ringed planet in [no-manys-sky](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/no-manys-sky) with 13 upvotes!

[image: Last week's winning screenshot]

To submit a screenshot, simply post it as an answer to this question, but please take note of the following:

- One screenshot per post, and one post per person, please!
- Limited picture modifications are allowed, such as cropping, simple filters, and blurring of identifying info such as names, but not adding other images or text.
- To ensure a fair playing field, please post screenshots you've taken yourself rather than ones you found online.
- Stack Exchange’s [Code of Conduct](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/conduct) still applies - so if it would be unacceptable to post normally, it’s unacceptable here.

Also, try to avoid pictures that include spoilers. We want everyone to be able to enjoy this contest, so the less spoilers the better.

#### How long will the contest run?

We will accept submissions for a week, until 19:00 UTC of 2021-10-11, then have a second week-long period where only voting will be accepted. This is to give every submission, even those posted at the end of the first week, a chance to be voted on by everyone.

After the end of the second week, at 19:00 UTC of 2021-10-18, we will count upvotes only to determine the winning screenshot, which will be featured for a week on the main site's photo widget.

---

## No Theme

There's no theme this week, so just post the best screenshots you've got.

As a reminder, we're always accepting suggestions for themed weeks, and have compiled that suggestion process into a [question of its own](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15029/screenshot-of-the-week-themes).

Answer (score 18):

[image: Epic picture of Mario looking into the sun, warring sunglasses and knights armorer with moon dust flying around]

I like to call this one “Dank Mario” [super-mario-odyssey](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/super-mario-odyssey)

Answer (score 13):

[amnesia-rebirth](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/amnesia-rebirth) looks mighty fine. A rare non-scary scene.

[image]

Answer (score 8):

[image: Death Stranding]

The end of the first leg of your westward journey in [death-stranding](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/death-stranding)

Comment: the blue at the top is actually a side effect of https://tinypng.com/ compression as the file on my PC was still 2.39MB which is too big for Stack Exchange's upload

Comment: It does say it's "lossy" compression but that blue is terrible. Would have been better to just lower the resolution or upload a JPG version.

Comment: So this a game that realistically depicts how much gear you are carrying? Rather than having 500 lbs of gear and nothing visible on your toon, not even a backpack.

Comment: @LoreFriendly name checks out

Comment: It reminds me of my mother waddling off the bus from town like a little hero.

Comment: [Dé jà vu](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14810/163757)

Answer (score 7):

This death really knocked me off my feet. [counter-strike-global-offensive](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/counter-strike-global-offensive)

[image]

Answer (score 6):

The birth of a legend in [super-mario-rpg](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/super-mario-rpg)

[image]

Comment: I'm a simple man. I see Super Mario RPG, I  upvote.

Answer (score 6):

The inner core of a planet in [astroneer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/astroneer).

[image: core]

Answer (score 6):

Getting spun around by a painful bat-to-the-face in [days-gone](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/days-gone)

[image: Deacon spinning to face the camera after being hit]

Answer (score 4):

Now entering the Cyber World in [deltarune](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/deltarune)

[image: Ralsei, Susie, and Kris line up and prepare to explore the Cyber World]