# Screenshot of the Week #100: Celebration edition!

Tags: discussion, community-event, screenshot-of-the-week

## This contest is over.

*[previous contest](//meta.arqade.com/q/16884/) | [next contest](//meta.arqade.com/q/16921/)*

Hello and welcome to the **100<sup>th</sup>** edition of the Screenshot of the Week! Wait, 100th?!!? Wow! That's right, this is the **100<sup>th</sup>** time we've done Screenshot of the Week. [Suggested by Joachim](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14681/what-type-of-community-events-would-you-like-to-see/14685#14685), and inspired by a similar event over on Photo.SE, the mod team never imagined that the SOTW would go on to be this successful. While the whole mod team loved the idea, we were worried the community might get bored of it after a few months. To say the least, our worries were completely unwarranted, since we've been running the contest for [nearly 4 years now!](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14741/screenshot-of-the-week-contest-1). This community event never would have lasted this long or been this successful if it wasn't for you, the Arqade Community. **Thank you for being so amazingly awesome, Arqade Community!**

So, given this is the 100th edition of SOTW, we need to do something special, right? Well, luckily we've got something special in store for you! The Mod team decided that the "theme" for this week is going to be a celebration of the screenshot of the week itself! Instead of posting new screenshots, we're going to post old ones. Post your favourite previously entered screenshots, and vote them to the top! The only restrictions are:

- You can't submit a screenshot submitted by yourself
- You can't submit a previous winner

With that out of the way... congratulations to the winner of the previous contest! [Joachim](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/16890/8350)'s picture from [baldurs-gate-3](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/baldurs-gate-3) won with 10 upvotes!

[image: Last week's winning screenshot one]

---

To submit a screenshot, simply post it as an answer to this question, but please take note of the following:

- One screenshot per post, and one post per person, please!

The other, usual limitations don't apply in this special case, since we can assume any screenshots posted in the past are up to code.

Also, try to avoid pictures that include spoilers. We want everyone to be able to enjoy this contest, so the less spoilers the better.

#### How long will the contest run?

We will accept submissions for a week, until 19:00 UTC of 2023-10-09, then have a second week-long period where only voting will be accepted. This is to give every submission, even those posted at the end of the first week, a chance to be voted on by everyone.

After the end of the second week, at 19:00 UTC of 2023-10-16, we will count upvotes only to determine the winning screenshot, which will be featured for a week on the main site's photo widget.

---

## 100th Celebration edition!

In celebration of the 100th edition of the SOTW, the theme this week is celebration of the SOTW itself! Submit your favourite previously entered screenshots, and then vote them to the top! The only restrictions are:

- You can't submit a screenshot submitted by yourself
- You can't submit a previous winner

As a reminder, we're always accepting suggestions for themed weeks, and have compiled that suggestion process into a [question of its own](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15029/screenshot-of-the-week-themes).  Additionally, there is the [hall of fame](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14939/screenshot-of-the-week-hall-of-fame) you can check out that contains all the previous contest winners.

Comment: For reference, most of the winning images have been compiled in [this one post](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14939/screenshot-of-the-week-hall-of-fame)

Comment: Are winners excluded? If the one submitter so far agrees, it could even be added as a rule, I think that would be fun. Most of us have already seen the previous winners.

Comment: @FabianRöling Not a bad idea. I'll bring it up with the other mods and see what they think.

Comment: it would be more difficult to search for non-winning entries, one would have to open every contest instead of just all winners post

Comment: I've edited the description to exclude previous winners. 

Comment: I wish I had the time to search for another submission in old contests, this was a very nice idea

Comment: I did that by clicking on the tag, opening all entries in new tabs and then quickly scrolling through, looking for my own upvotes on non-accepted answers. Took <5min total, then some more for deciding which one of them I wanted to post again here.

Comment: Good for you, I have a very slow decision process

Comment: I had set a reminder for shortly before the end of the vote period. I could have made it a 4-way tie!

Comment: @Joachim Done like dinner

Answer (score 12, accepted):

While from a recent contest ([98](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16872/screenshot-of-the-week-98)), [pinckerman's](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/users/87579/pinckerman) submission of sunset photography looks amazing.

[image]

Comment: Oh, thanks for reposting this :)

Answer (score 11):

From [Contest #80 Happy Holidays 2022](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/16625/163757) by [Joachim](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/222022/joachim):

> Hugo lighting candles in [a-plague-tale-innocence](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/a-plague-tale-innocence)

[image]

Something about this one just hits me. Never played the game, maybe Joachim can add some context as to what's going on here.

Comment: Having played the game, Hugo is lighting a candle for his parents who were killed in an attack by Inquisitors, who in turn had to run for his life with his sister

Comment: @Wondercricket so what does that have to do with the holiday season?!

Comment: I missed the fact that it was posted the holiday season theme, so now I’m just as confused as you are

Comment: Thank you for providing the background information, @Wondercricket. The December holidays are Christmas-heavy, and, having been raised religiously, I guess lighting candles in an old church seems very winter holidays-y to me (the moving story behind it didn't matter, since it can't be gleaned from the image, and what's left is just that possibly very subjective association :).

Answer (score 11):

From [Contest #12](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15079/screenshot-of-the-week-contest-12), by [Wondercricket](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/users/124566/wondercricket)

> I somehow managed to capture this in [final-fantasy-7-remake](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/final-fantasy-7-remake)

[image: Fiery Tornado]

This is such an epic capture from such an iconic game.

Answer (score 10):

I cannot understand how [this](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/16498/171580) submission by [Memor-X](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/30879/memor-x) did not win #71. It has cats!

[image: aaaaa]

Original text:

> Cats love Mario in [bowsers-fury](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bowsers-fury) (and yes, the Switch does vibrate when they do this)

Comment: would have been a draw had i not voted for Batophobia's submission lol

Answer (score 10):

From [Contest #63](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/16392/144891), by [Neon1024](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/users/5357/neon1024)

> Visiting The Gauntlet system in early access [everspace-2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/everspace-2)

[image: The Gauntlet system in Everspace 2 early access]

Comment: is your space ship supposed to look like a weird scifi pistol?

Answer (score 9):

From [Contest #8: Scenery](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14975/239518) by [murgatroid99](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/users/1787/murgatroid99)

> View from the beginning of the mission Halo in [halo-anniversary](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/halo-anniversary)

[image]

Comment: The first time landing on Halo in CE 22 years ago... is a feeling I won't forget

Comment: @TimmyJim I knew I had to submit it as I was scrolling through past submissions, I have the Halo skybox as my home in Steam VR!

Answer (score 8):

From [Contest #15 - The 90's](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/15167/28182), by [Batophobia](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/42984/batophobia)

> "Well Done" - [earthworm-jim-2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/earthworm-jim-2)

[image: Cows in Earthworm Jim 2]

I just really liked the low res cartoony aesthetic of these cows, it's one that I remember wishing got more love back when the contest ran

Comment: There is no cow level!

Comment: The steaks.... I mean stakes are high with this post

Comment: I am for some reason reminded of the diablo cows easter egg

Comment: @TimmyJim Maybe because Amarth was referring to that :)

Answer (score 6):

From [Contest #2](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14773/screenshot-of-the-week-contest-2), by [Smock](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/users/228394/smock)

> I guess that's what double white lines are for... - [euro-truck-simulator-2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/euro-truck-simulator-2)

[image: screenshot]

Trucks hugging?

Answer (score 4):

[image]

---

From [Contest #47](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/screenshot-of-the-week-47) by [fwoosh](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/232493)