# Screenshot of the Week - Hall of Fame

Tags: discussion, community-event, screenshot-of-the-week

Since the [screenshot-of-the-week](/questions/tagged/screenshot-of-the-week) contest was based on the 'Photo of the Week' contest of our Photography sister website (see [here](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/featured-photo)), a corresponding 'Hall of Fame' has been suggested ([here](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14685/222022)), to showcase the winners and possibly gain even more attention from the community.

This is that.

Comment: I like it, thank you for getting the previous ones together in one place

Comment: If each winner would be one "answer", we could vote on our favourites and people could e.g. see which ones were the most popular of all time.

Comment: Someone needs to learn about the law of thirds, these are all way too central

Answer (score 15):

### Screenshot of the Week Winners #1 - #25

**→ #1 - #25** (You are here)
**→ [#26 - #50](//meta.arqade.com/a/15451)**
**→ [#51 - #75](//meta.arqade.com/a/16149)**
**→ [#76 - #100](//meta.arqade.com/a/16582)**
**→ [#101 - #125](//meta.arqade.com/a/16934)**

---

#### [Contest #1](//meta.arqade.com/q/14741)

**Date:** 27th Nov, 2019 - 11th Dec, 2019 | **Winner:** [Robotnik](//arqade.com/users/28182/robotnik?tab=profile) | **Game:** [pokemon-sword-shield](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pokemon-sword-shield)

[image: Wild Farfetch'd used Leer! - winning screenshot contest 1]
*Farfetch'd giving me the biggest evils*

---

#### [Contest #2](//meta.arqade.com/q/14773)

**Date:** 19th Dec, 2019 - 27th Dec, 2019 | **Winner:** [Wondercricket](//arqade.com/users/124566/wondercricket?tab=profile) | **Game:** [no-mans-sky](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/no-mans-sky)

[image: Bubbles bubbles everywhere but not a drop to drink - winning screenshot contest 2]
*"Bubbles! Bubbles! My bubbles."*

---

#### [Contest #3](//meta.arqade.com/q/14807)

**Date:** 27th Dec, 2019 - 10th Jan, 2020 | **Winner:** [PausePause](//arqade.com/users/228910/pausepause?tab=profile) | **Game:** [the-elder-scrolls-5-skyrim](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-elder-scrolls-5-skyrim)

[image: At this time of year, at this time of day, in this part of the country, localized entirely within Skyrim? - winning screenshot contest 3]
*A scenic aurora*

---

#### [Contest #4](//meta.arqade.com/q/14828)

**Date:** 10th Jan, 2020 - 27th Jan, 2020 | **Winner:** [arghtype](//arqade.com/users/144891/arghtype?tab=profile) | **Game:** [dark-souls-3](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dark-souls-3)

[image: bat-moon - winning screenshot contest 4]
*Me in Set of Thorns with Black Knight Axe in Irithyll of the Boreal Valley*

---

#### [Contest #5 - Glitches and Bugs](//meta.arqade.com/q/14863)

**Date:** 27th Jan, 2020 - 10th Feb, 2020 | **Winner:** [Unionhawk](//arqade.com/users/20306/unionhawk?tab=profile) | **Game:** [euro-truck-simulator-2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/euro-truck-simulator-2)

[image: truck driving on a river - winning screenshot contest 5]
*Beep beep*

---

#### [Contest #6 - Wildlife](//meta.arqade.com/q/14912)

**Date:** 10th Feb, 2020 - 24th Feb, 2020 | **Winner:** [arghtype](//arqade.com/users/144891/arghtype?tab=profile) | **Game:** [sekiro-shadows-die-twice](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sekiro-shadows-die-twice)

[image: Character hiding from giant snake - winning screenshot contest 6]
*Hiding from local wildlife*

---

#### [Contest #7](//meta.arqade.com/q/14932)

**Date:** 24th Feb, 2020 - 9th Mar, 2020 | **Winner:** [Riley](//arqade.com/users/148364/riley?tab=profile) | **Game:** [elite-dangerous](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/elite-dangerous)

[image: a gorgeous deep purple planet - winning screenshot contest 7]
*From the tourist destination aptly named The View*

---

#### [Contest #8 - Scenery](//meta.arqade.com/q/14966)

**Date:** 9th Mar, 2020 - 23rd Mar, 2020 | **Winner:** [Wondercricket](//arqade.com/users/124566/wondercricket?tab=profile) | **Game:** [shadow-of-the-colossus](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/shadow-of-the-colossus)

[image: Shadow of the colossus world - winning screenshot contest 8]
*A vast plain*

---

#### [Contest #9](//meta.arqade.com/q/14994)

**Date:** 23rd Mar, 2020 - 6th Apr, 2020 | **Winner:** [Batophobia](//arqade.com/users/42984/batophobia?tab=profile) | **Game:** [the-stanley-parable](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-stanley-parable)

[image: Companion Cube in The Stanley Parable - winning screenshot contest 9]
*Stanley finally got the memo to work from home, so now there's a new workforce at the office.*

---

#### [Contest #10](//meta.arqade.com/q/15013)

**Date:** 6th Apr, 2020 - 20th Apr, 2020 | **Winner:** [Fabian Röling](//arqade.com/users/171580/fabian-r%C3%B6ling?tab=profile) | **Game:** [minecraft](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft)

[image: skeleton and creeper overlapping - winning screenshot contest 10]
*Something about this skeleton seems more dangerous than usual...*

---

#### [Contest #11 - Moments Before Disaster](//meta.arqade.com/q/15042)

**Date:** 20th Apr, 2020 - 4th May, 2020 | **Winner:** [Ronan](//arqade.com/users/4012/ronan?tab=profile) | **Game:** [animal-crossing-new-horizons](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/animal-crossing-new-horizons)

[image: tarantula ready to strike! - winning screenshot contest 11]
*Pouncing Tiger Beetles*

---

#### [Contest #12](//meta.arqade.com/q/15079)

**Date:** 4th May, 2020 - 18th May, 2020 | **Winner:** [Booga Roo](//arqade.com/users/136881/booga-roo?tab=profile) | **Game:** [monster-hunter-world](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/monster-hunter-world)

[image: silly costumes in a serious conversation - winning screenshot contest 12]
*It's really hard to take the handler seriously when she's wearing that palico costume.*

---

#### [Contest #13 - Residence](//meta.arqade.com/q/15111)

**Date:** 18th May, 2020 - 1st Jun, 2020 | **Winner:** [Dragonrage](//arqade.com/users/127901/dragonrage?tab=profile) | **Game:** [rust](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rust)

[image: A sprawling base - winning screenshot contest 13]
*In a post-apocalyptic world, its good to have a bunker base to keep the zergs out.*

---

#### [Contest #14](//meta.arqade.com/q/15134)

**Date:** 1st Jun, 2020 - 15th Jun, 2020 | **Winner:** [Robotnik](//arqade.com/users/28182/robotnik?tab=profile) | **Game:** [fallout-4](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fallout-4)

[image: Spent Bullet Cartridge - winning screenshot contest 14]
*A bullet cartridge on it's way to my face in Fallout 4*

---

#### [Contest #15 - 90s](//meta.arqade.com/q/15164)

**Date:** 15th Jun, 2020 - 29th Jun, 2020 | **Winner:** [Dragonrage](//arqade.com/users/127901/dragonrage?tab=profile) | **Game:** [sim-ant](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sim-ant)

[image: ants in Sim Ant - winning screenshot contest 15]
*I had a ton of fun playing this back in the day, and after I tired of playing as an ant, I also liked playing as a spider and eating as many ants as I could.*

---

#### [Contest #16](//meta.arqade.com/q/15185)

**Date:** 29th Jun, 2020 - 13th Jul, 2020 | **Winner:** [Unionhawk](//arqade.com/users/20306/unionhawk?tab=profile) | **Game:** [sea-of-thieves](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sea-of-thieves)

[image: flying sailship - winning screenshot contest 16]
*Wherein my ship begins going to space prior to disconnecting*

---

#### [Contest #17 - Victory](//meta.arqade.com/q/15204)

**Date:** 13th Jul, 2020 - 27th Jul, 2020 | **Winner:** [Booga Roo](//arqade.com/users/136881/booga-roo?tab=profile) | **Game:** [zelda-breath-of-the-wild](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/zelda-breath-of-the-wild)

[image: Link's Master Sword - winning screenshot contest 17]
*This is Link's victory pose as he earns the fully restored power of the Master Sword.*

---

#### [Contest #18](//meta.arqade.com/q/15231)

**Date:** 27th Jul, 2020 - 10th Aug, 2020 | **Winner:** [dly](//arqade.com/users/117067/dly?tab=profile) | **Game:** [rust](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rust)

[image: pool relaxation - winning screenshot contest 18]
*Let everyone else kill each other. I'm enjoying a hot summer day in my pool in Rust.*

---

#### [Contest #19 - Space Exploration](//meta.arqade.com/q/15260)

**Date:** 10th Aug, 2020 - 24th Aug, 2020 | **Winner:** [Fabian Röling](//arqade.com/users/171580/fabian-r%C3%B6ling?tab=profile) | **Game:** [super-mario-galaxy-2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/super-mario-galaxy-2)

[image: Yoshi's stuck tongue - winning screenshot contest 19]
*Yoshi went to space, but his tongue didn't want to come along.*

---

#### [Contest #20](//meta.arqade.com/q/15278)

**Date:** 24th Aug, 2020 - 7th Sep, 2020 | **Winner:** [GnomeSlice](//arqade.com/users/3114/gnomeslice?tab=profile) | **Game:** [borderlands-3](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/borderlands-3)

[image: Coolant and Heatant - winning screenshot contest 20]
*Admiring engineering in Borderlands 3*

---

#### [Contest #21- Classic Games](//meta.arqade.com/q/15308)

**Date:** 7th Sep, 2020 - 21st Sep, 2020 | **Winner:** [Riley](//arqade.com/users/148364/riley?tab=profile) | **Game:** [assassins-creed](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/assassins-creed)

[image: Assassin's Creed opening - winning screenshot contest 21]
*The opening sequence of assassins-creed (2007) never ceased to impress me*

---

#### [Contest #22](//meta.arqade.com/q/15318)

**Date:** 21st Sep, 2020 - 5th Oct, 2020 | **Winner:** [Rory O'Kane](//arqade.com/users/28422/rory-okane?tab=profile) | **Game:** [watch-dogs-2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/watch-dogs-2)

[image: San Francisco Bay - winning screenshot contest 22]
*A view of San Francisco Bay from a tiny, rocky island.*

---

#### [Contest #23 - Water Scenes](//meta.arqade.com/q/15342)

**Date:** 5th Oct, 2020 - 19th Oct, 2020 | **Winner:** [SaintWacko](//arqade.com/users/15092/saintwacko?tab=profile) | **Game:** [sea-of-thieves](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sea-of-thieves)

[image: sunrise - winning screenshot contest 23]
*Sunrise in Sea of Thieves*

---

#### [Contest #24 - Halloween](//meta.arqade.com/q/15375)

**Date:** 20th Oct, 2020 - 2nd Nov, 2020 | **Winner:** [Wrigglenite](//arqade.com/users/143571/wrigglenite?tab=profile) | **Game:** [monster-hunter-world](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/monster-hunter-world)

[image: character and their palico - winning screenshot contest 24]
*Me and my Palico getting in the right mood for spooks*

---

#### [Contest #25](//meta.arqade.com/q/15393)

**Date:** 9th Nov - 16th Nov, 2020 | **Winner:** [Robotnik](//arqade.com/users/28182/robotnik?tab=profile) | **Game:** [horizon-zero-dawn](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/horizon-zero-dawn)

[image: flowers at night - winning screenshot contest 25]
*Flowers at night in Horizon Zero Dawn*

---

**Jump to:**

**→ #1 - #25** (You are here)
**→ [#26 - #50](//meta.arqade.com/a/15451)**
**→ [#51 - #75](//meta.arqade.com/a/16149)**
**→ [#76 - #100](//meta.arqade.com/a/16582)**
**→ [#101 - #125](//meta.arqade.com/a/16934)**

Answer (score 12):

### Screenshot of the Week Winners #26 - #50

**→ [#1 - #25](//meta.arqade.com/a/15414)**
**→ #26 - #50** (You are here)
**→ [#51 - #75](//meta.arqade.com/a/16149)**
**→ [#76 - #100](//meta.arqade.com/a/16582)**
**→ [#101 - #125](//meta.arqade.com/a/16934)**

---

#### [Contest #26 - Loading Screens](//meta.arqade.com/q/15412)

**Date:** 16th Nov, 2020 - 30th Nov, 2020 | **Winner:** [Unionhawk](//arqade.com/users/20306/unionhawk?tab=profile) | **Game:** [microsoft-flight-simulator](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/microsoft-flight-simulator)

[image: cessna 172 skyhawk - winning screenshot contest 26]
*I love when loading screens hit me with cool facts about the world, and this cool fact about the Cessna 172 Skyhawk in Microsoft Flight Simulator is a good one.*

---

#### [Contest #27](//meta.arqade.com/q/15447)

**Date:** 30th Nov, 2020 - 14th Dec, 2020 | **Winner:** [arghtype](//arqade.com/users/144891/arghtype?tab=profile) | **Game:** [mortal-shell](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mortal-shell)

[image: knight wielding a giant sword - winning screenshot contest 27]
*Wielding a big sword in Mortal Shell*

---

#### [Contest #28 - Holiday](//meta.arqade.com/q/15474)

**Date:** 14th Dec, 2020 - 28th Dec, 2020 | **Winner:** [Booga Roo](//arqade.com/users/136881/booga-roo?tab=profile) | **Game:** [deep-rock-galactic](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/deep-rock-galactic)

[image: a very festive bar - winning screenshot contest 28]
*Free beer at the bar in Deep Rock Galactic*

---

#### [Contest #29](//meta.arqade.com/q/15496)

**Date:** 28th Dec, 2020 - 18th Jan, 2021 | **Winner:** [Batophobia](//arqade.com/users/42984/batophobia?tab=profile) | **Game:** [horizon-zero-dawn](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/horizon-zero-dawn)

[image: Aloy ready to strike - winning screenshot contest 29]
*Hunting robots in Horizon Zero Dawn*

---

#### [Contest #30 - Game of the Year 2020](//meta.arqade.com/q/15511)

**Date:** 11th Jan, 2021 - 25th Jan, 2021 | **Winner:** [K00lman](//arqade.com/users/237554/k00lman?tab=profile) | **Game:** [half-life-alyx](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/half-life-alyx)

[image: bottle mid-air - winning screenshot contest 30]
*A lot of Half-Life: Alyx is beautiful, but the bottles just take the cake*

---

#### [Contest #31](//meta.arqade.com/q/15534)

**Date:** 25th Jan, 2021 - 8th Feb, 2021 | **Winner:** [Raven Dreamer](//arqade.com/users/336/raven-dreamer?tab=profile) | **Game:** [crusader-kings-3](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/crusader-kings-3)

[image: poetry for emperor fernando - winning screenshot contest 31]
*What happens when you become the Emperor of Hispania in Crusader Kings 3? You start to receive poetry from your adoring admirers, of course.*

---

#### [Contest #32 - Easter Eggs](//meta.arqade.com/q/15569)

**Date:** 8th Feb, 2021 - 22nd Feb, 2021 | **Winner:** [arghtype](//arqade.com/users/144891/arghtype?tab=profile) | **Game:** [risk-of-rain-2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/risk-of-rain-2)

[image: giant easter eggs - winning screenshot contest 32]
*Actual Easter Eggs in Risk of Rain 2*

---

#### [Contest #33](//meta.arqade.com/q/15604)

**Date:** 22nd Feb, 2021 - 8th Mar, 2021 | **Winner:** [Kaizerwolf](//arqade.com/users/91583/kaizerwolf?tab=profile) | **Game:** [shadow-of-the-colossus-2018](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/shadow-of-the-colossus-2018)

[image: a waterfall lagoon - winning screenshot contest 33]
*I recently finished the Shadow of the Colossus remaster. I never played the original on PS2, but bluepoint did a beautiful job on the look of the game.*

---

#### [Contest #34 - Winter](//meta.arqade.com/q/15641)

**Date:** 8th Mar, 2021 - 22nd Mar, 2021 | **Winner:** [arghtype](//arqade.com/users/144891/arghtype?tab=profile) | **Game:** [horizon-zero-dawn](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/horizon-zero-dawn)

[image: a frozen dam view - winning screenshot contest 34]
*Enjoying frozen dam view in Horizon Zero Dawn*

---

#### [Contest #35](//meta.arqade.com/q/15682)

**Date:** 23rd Mar, 2021 - 5th Apr, 2021 | **Winner:** [Marc_Alx](//arqade.com/users/121095/marc-alx?tab=profile) | **Game:** [assassins-creed-origins](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/assassins-creed-origins)

[image: Flight of flamingos over Memphis (Egypt) - winning screenshot contest 35]
*Flight of flamingos over Memphis (Egypt) in Assassin's Creed: Origins*

---

#### [Contest #36 - Giant Monsters](//meta.arqade.com/q/15718)

**Date:** 5th Apr, 2021 - 19th Apr, 2021 | **Winner:** [n00dles](//arqade.com/users/170898/n00dles?tab=profile) | **Game:** [no-mans-sky](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/no-mans-sky)

[image: A giant larva from outer space - winning screenshot contest 36]
*You have to look pretty close to see my ship!*

---

#### [Contest #37](//meta.arqade.com/q/15753)

**Date:** 19th Apr, 2021 - 3rd May, 2021 | **Winner:** [Roddy of the Frozen Peas](//arqade.com/users/44445/roddy-of-the-frozen-peas?tab=profile) | **Game:** [the-outer-worlds](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-outer-worlds)

[image: lava plumes on Terra 2 - winning screenshot contest 37]
*A Surprisingly Breathtaking View (as long as it isn't trying to kill you)*

---

#### [Contest #38 - Into The Storm](//meta.arqade.com/q/15804)

**Date:** 3rd May, 2021 - 18th May, 2021 | **Winner:** [DefaultSimon](//arqade.com/users/205599/defaultsimon?tab=profile) | **Game:** [death-stranding](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/death-stranding)

[image: Sam heading towards the supercell - winning screenshot contest 38]
*Sam Porter Bridges on his way towards the supercell*

---

#### [Contest #39](//meta.arqade.com/q/15837)

**Date:** 18th May, 2021 - 31st May, 2021 | **Winner:** [Robotnik](//arqade.com/users/28182/robotnik?tab=profile) | **Game:** [the-outer-worlds](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-outer-worlds)

[image: Phineas' Lab with The Hope - winning screenshot contest 39]
*Phineas' Lab with The Hope, orbiting above Terra 2*

---

#### [Contest #40](//meta.arqade.com/q/15851)

**Date:** 31st May, 2021 - 14th June, 2021| **Winner:** [Booga Roo](//arqade.com/users/136881/booga-roo?tab=profile) | **Game:** [enslaved-odyssey-to-the-west](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/enslaved-odyssey-to-the-west)

[image: Monkey versus Dog - winning screenshot contest 40]
*Monkey versus Dog*

---

#### [Contest #41](//meta.arqade.com/q/15870)

**Date:** 14th June, 2021 - 28th June, 2021 | **Winner:** [Wipqozn](//arqade.com/users/8350/wipqozn?tab=profile) | **Game:** [parkitect](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/parkitect)

[image: My Archipelago Adventures park - winning screenshot contest 41]
*My Archipelago Adventures park*

---

#### [Contest #42](//meta.arqade.com/q/15905)

**Date:** 28th June, 2021 - 12th July, 2021 | **Winner:** [Batophobia](//arqade.com/users/42984/batophobia?tab=profile) | **Game:** [titanfall-2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/titanfall-2)

[image: Stopping time to admire explosions in Titanfall 2 - winning screenshot contest 42]
*Stopping time to admire explosions in Titanfall 2*

---

#### [Contest #43](//meta.arqade.com/q/15929)

**Date:** 12th July, 2021 - 26th July, 2021 | **Winner:** [Joachim](//arqade.com/users/222022/joachim?tab=profile) | **Game:** [the-witcher-3](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-witcher-3)

[image: Geralt's way of dealing with adverse precipitation - winning screenshot contest 43]
*Geralt's way of dealing with adverse precipitation*

---

#### [Contest #44](//meta.arqade.com/q/15962)

**Date:** 26th July, 2021 - 9th August, 2021 | **Winner:** [SaintWacko](//arqade.com/users/15092/saintwacko?tab=profile) | **Game:** [path-of-exile](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/path-of-exile)

[image: RNGesus giveth, and RNGesus taketh away - winning screenshot contest 44]
*RNGesus giveth, and RNGesus taketh away*

---

#### [Contest #45](//meta.arqade.com/q/16007)

**Date:** 9th August, 2021 - 23rd August, 2021 | **Winner:** [DefaultSimon](//arqade.com/users/205599/defaultsimon?tab=profile) | **Game:** [horizon-zero-dawn](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/horizon-zero-dawn)

[image: Unwinding just outside Horizon Zero Dawn's Sunfall, looking over hoodoos and dunes as the day rolls into a vibrant evening. - winning screenshot contest 45]
*Unwinding just outside Horizon Zero Dawn's Sunfall, looking over hoodoos and dunes as the day rolls into a vibrant evening.*

---

#### [Contest #46 - Character Customization!](//meta.arqade.com/q/16054)

**Date:** 23rd August, 2021 - 6th September, 2021 | **Winner:** [arghtype](//arqade.com/users/144891/arghtype?tab=profile) | **Game:** [dark-souls-3](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dark-souls-3)

[image: This scene doesn't look that serious when you are some funny mustache guy. - winning screenshot contest 46]
*This scene doesn't look that serious when you are some funny mustache guy.*

---

#### [Contest #47](//meta.arqade.com/q/16065)

**Date:** 2021 - 6th September, 2021 - 20th September, 2021 | **Winner:** [pinckerman](//arqade.com/users/87579/pinckerman?tab=profile) | **Game:** [immortals-fenyx-rising](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/immortals-fenyx-rising)

[image: Cuddling my beloved winged partner Phosphor from Immortals Fenyx Rising - winning screenshot contest 47]
*Cuddling my beloved winged partner Phosphor from Immortals Fenyx Rising*

---

#### [Contest #48 - Nighttime](//meta.arqade.com/q/16092)

**Date:** 2021 - 20th September, 2021 - 4th October, 2021 | **Winner:** [pinckerman](//arqade.com/users/87579/pinckerman?tab=profile) | **Game:** [no-mans-sky](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/no-mans-sky)

[image: Admiring the horizon of a ringed planet in No Man's Sky]
*Admiring the horizon of a ringed planet in No Man's Sky*

---

#### [Contest #49](//meta.arqade.com/q/16106)

**Date:** 2021 - 4th October, 2021 - 18th October, 2021 | **Winner:** [Morgan](//arqade.com/users/273137/morgan?tab=profile) | **Game:** [super-mario-odyssey](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/super-mario-odyssey)

[image: I like to call this one “Dank Mario”]
*I like to call this one “Dank Mario”*

---

#### [Contest #50 - Halloween](//meta.arqade.com/q/16120)

**Date:** 2021 - 19th October, 2021 - 1st November, 2021 | **Winners:** [Ismael Miguel](//arqade.com/users/101294/ismael-miguel?tab=profile) & [GammaGames](//arqade.com/users/239518/gammagames?tab=profile) | **Game:** [blade-and-soul](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/blade-and-soul) & [animal-crossing-new-horizons](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/animal-crossing-new-horizons)

[image: Blade and Soul's Lobby for Halloween]
*Blade and Soul's Lobby for Halloween*

[image: My pumpkin patch in Animal Crossing New Horizons]
*My pumpkin patch in Animal Crossing New Horizons*

---

**Jump to:**

**→ [#1 - #25](//meta.arqade.com/a/15414)**
**→ #26 - #50** (You are here)
**→ [#51 - #75](//meta.arqade.com/a/16149)**
**→ [#76 - #100](//meta.arqade.com/a/16582)**
**→ [#101 - #125](//meta.arqade.com/a/16934)**

Answer (score 8):

### Screenshot of the Week Winners #51 - #75

**→ [#1 - #25](//meta.arqade.com/a/15414)**
**→ [#26 - #50](//meta.arqade.com/a/15451)**
**→ #51 - #75** (You are here)
**→ [#76 - #100](//meta.arqade.com/a/16582)**
**→ [#101 - #125](//meta.arqade.com/a/16934)**

---

#### [Contest #51](//meta.arqade.com/q/16136)

**Date:** 2021 - 1st November, 2021 - 15th November | **Winner:** [Timmy Jim](//arqade.com/users/163757/timmy-jim?tab=profile) | **Game:** [new-world](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/new-world)

[image: Shattered Obelisk in New World]
*Shattered Obelisk in New World*

---

#### [Contest #52 - Hero Pose](//meta.arqade.com/q/16148)

**Date:** 2021 - 15th November, 2021 - 30th November | **Winners:** [Timmy Jim](//arqade.com/users/163757/timmy-jim?tab=profile) & [Robotnik](//arqade.com/users/28182/robotnik?tab=profile) | **Games:** [oldschool-runescape](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/oldschool-runescape), [team-fortress-2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/team-fortress-2)

[image: Strength Cape Emote]
*The Strength Cape emote in Oldschool Runescape*

[image: Bucket of Chicken]
*Hey there, good lookin! I got a bucket o' chicken, let's do this!*

---

#### [Contest #53](//meta.arqade.com/q/16160)

**Date:** 2021 - 30th November, 2021 - 14th December | **Winner:** [arghtype](//arqade.com/users/144891/arghtype?tab=profile) | **Game:** [days-gone](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/days-gone)

[image: evening ride in Days Gone]
*Enjoying an evening ride in Days Gone*

---

#### [Contest #54 - Happy Holidays 2021](//meta.arqade.com/q/16171)

**Date:** 2021 - 14th December, 2021 - 28th December | **Winner:** [Timmy Jim](//arqade.com/users/163757/timmy-jim?tab=profile) | **Game:** [new-world](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/new-world)

[image: The tree is up in Everfall]
*It's the holiday season in [new-world](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/new-world). The tree is up in Everfall.*

---

#### [Contest #55](//meta.arqade.com/q/16183)

**Date:** 2021 - 28th December, 2022 - 10th January| **Winner:** [Joachim](//arqade.com/users/222022/joachim?tab=profile) | **Game:** [a-plague-tale-innocence](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/a-plague-tale-innocence)

[image: Stumbling upon a body-strewn battlefield]
*Stumbling upon a body-strewn battlefield in [a-plague-tale-innocence](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/a-plague-tale-innocence).*

---

#### [Contest #56 - Sweet Rides](//meta.arqade.com/q/16210)

**Date:** 2022 - 10th January, 2022 - 24th January | **Winner:** [arghtype](//arqade.com/users/144891/arghtype?tab=profile) | **Game:** [returnal](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/returnal)

[image: This is Helios. It was a nice ship, until I crash-landed on this damn planet. But then I crashed on it again. And again]
*This is Helios. It was a nice ship, until I crash-landed on this damn planet. But then I crashed on it again. And again.*

---

#### [Contest #57](//meta.arqade.com/q/16229)

**Date:** 2022 - 24th January, 2022 - 7th February | **Winner:** [batophobia](//arqade.com/users/42984/batophobia?tab=profile) | **Game:** [manifold-garden](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/manifold-garden)

[image: Manifold Garden has me feeling like a 4D creature trying to live in a 3D world.]
*Manifold Garden has me feeling like a 4D creature trying to live in a 3D world.*

---

#### [Contest #58 - Pets](//meta.arqade.com/q/16245)

**Date:** 2022 - 8th February, 2022 - 22nd February | **Winner:** [pinckerman](//arqade.com/users/87579/pinckerman?tab=profile) | **Game:** [pokemon-legends-arceus](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pokemon-legends-arceus)

[image: Here is my good boy Eneru from pokemon-legends-arceus]
*Here is my good boy Eneru from Pokemon Legends: Arceus.*

---

#### [Contest #59](//meta.arqade.com/q/16262)

**Date:** 2022 - 22nd February, 2022 - 8th March | **Winner:** [Memor-X](//arqade.com/users/30879/memor-x?tab=profile) | **Game:** [atelier-escha-and-logy](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/atelier-escha-and-logy)

[image: Linca is about to destroy something in atelier-escha-and-logy]
*Linca is about to destroy something in Atelier Escha and Logy*

---

#### [Contest #60](//meta.arqade.com/q/16285)

**Date:** 2022 - 8th March, 2022 - 21st March | **Winner:** [Joachim](//arqade.com/users/222022/joachim?tab=profile) | **Game:** [control](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/control)

[image: It was me. I was the disaster. I was in Control.]
*It was me. I was the disaster. I was in Control.*

---

#### [Contest #61](//meta.arqade.com/q/16305)

**Date:** 2022 - 21st March, 2022 - 4th April | **Winners:** [Joachim](//arqade.com/users/222022/joachim?tab=profile) and [Memor-X](//arqade.com/users/30879/memor-x?tab=profile) | **Games:** [a-plague-tale-innocence](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/a-plague-tale-innocence) and [final-fantasy-xiv](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/final-fantasy-xiv)

[image: A Plague Tale Innocence is a visual treasure trove.]

*A Plague Tale Innocence is a visual treasure trove.*

[image: Limsa Lominsa at night during the Little Ladies Day event in]

*Limsa Lominsa at night during the Little Ladies Day event in Final Fantasy XIV.*

---

#### [Contest #62 - Bosses and Villains](//meta.arqade.com/q/16320)

**Date:** 2022 - 4th April, 2022 - 18th April  | **Winner:** [Batophobia](//arqade.com/users/42984/batophobia?tab=profile) | **Game:** [super-mario-3d-allstars](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/super-mario-3d-allstars)

[image: Respecting the classics in Super Mario 3D Allstars]
*Respecting the classics in Super Mario 3D Allstars*

---

#### [Contest #63](//meta.arqade.com/q/16335)

**Date:** 2022 - 18th April, 2022 - 2nd May  | **Winner:** [Batophobia](//arqade.com/users/42984/batophobia?tab=profile) | **Game:** [super-mario-3d-allstars](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/super-mario-3d-allstars)

[image: The psychedelic world of Psychonauts 2]
*The psychedelic world of Psychonauts 2*

---

#### [Contest #64 - The Great Outdoors](//meta.arqade.com/q/16413)

**Date:** 2022 - 2nd May, 2022 - 16th May | **Winner:** [pinckerman](//arqade.com/users/87579/pinckerman?tab=profile) | **Game:** [horizon-zero-dawn](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/horizon-zero-dawn)

[image: Panoramic view of Devil’s Thirst from the mountains in Horizon Zero Dawn]
*Panoramic view of Devil’s Thirst from the mountains in Horizon Zero Dawn*

---

#### [Contest #65](//meta.arqade.com/q/16426)

**Date:** 2022 - 16th May, 2022 - 30th May | **Winner:** [Memor-X](//arqade.com/users/30879/memor-x?tab=profile) | **Game:** [xenoblade-chronicles](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/xenoblade-chronicles)

[image: We measure! Find treasure! Ponspectors 'til we die!]
*We measure! Find treasure! Ponspectors 'til we die!*

---

#### [Contest #66](//meta.arqade.com/q/16441)

**Date:** 2022 - 30th May, 2022 - 13th June | **Winner:** [Batophobia](//arqade.com/users/42984/batophobia?tab=profile) | **Game:** [dragon-ball-z-kakarot](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dragon-ball-z-kakarot)

[image: Yamcha being Yamcha in dragon-ball-z-kakarot]
*Yamcha being Yamcha in Dragon Ball-Z Kakarot*

---

#### [Contest #67](//meta.arqade.com/q/16447)

**Date:** 2022 - 13th June, 2022 - 27th June | **Winner:** [Faither](//arqade.com/users/141102/faither?tab=profile) | **Game:** [the-elder-scrolls-online](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-elder-scrolls-online)

[image: The Elder Scrolls Online]
*The Elder Scrolls Online*

---

#### [Contest #68](//meta.arqade.com/q/16456) - Sheer Dominance

**Date:** 2022 - 27th June, 2022 - 11th July | **Winner:** [Joachim](//arqade.com/users/222022/joachim?tab=profile) | **Game:** [a-plague-tale-innocence](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/a-plague-tale-innocence)

[image: My little brother Hugo dominating the rats, the people present, and this image.]
*My little brother Hugo dominating the rats, the people present, and this image.*

---

#### [Contest #69](//meta.arqade.com/q/16468)

**Date:** 2022 - 11th July, 2022 - 25th July | **Winner:** [Dragonrage](//arqade.com/users/127901/dragonrage?tab=profile) | **Game:** [rust](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rust)

[image: A scientist slacking on his job in rust.]
*A scientist slacking on his job in Rust.*

---

#### [Contest #70 - Supernatural & Undead](//meta.arqade.com/q/16484)

**Date:** 2022 - 25th July, 2022 - 08th August | **Winner:** [Neonit](//arqade.com/users/236648/neonit?tab=profile) | **Game:** [the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim)

[image: The Ghost of Potema Septim, the Wolf Queen, as seen in the Wolfskull Cave in The Elder Scrolls V: Skyrim.]
*The Ghost of Potema Septim, the Wolf Queen, as seen in the Wolfskull Cave in The Elder Scrolls V: Skyrim..*

---

#### [Contest #71](//meta.arqade.com/q/16495)

**Date:** 2022 - 8th of August, 2022 - 22nd of August | **Winner:** [Faither](//arqade.com/users/141102/faither?tab=profile) | **Game:** [assassins-creed-odyssey](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/assassins-creed-odyssey)

[image: An eagle soaring high in the sky]
*Assassin's Creed: Odyssey*

---

#### [Contest #72 - Living with Nature](//meta.arqade.com/q/16508)

**Date:** 2022 - 22nd August, 2022 - 5th of September | **Winner:** [Joachim](//arqade.com/users/222022/joachim?tab=profile) | **Game:** [a-plague-tale-innocence](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/a-plague-tale-innocence)

[image: Finding respite and time to mourn in some overgrown castle ruins in A Plague Tale: Innocence]
*A Plague Tale: Innocence*

---

#### [Contest #73](//meta.arqade.com/q/16516)

**Date:** 2022 - 5th of September, 2022 - 19th of September | **Winner:** [Faither](//arqade.com/users/141102/faither?tab=profile) | **Game:** [mirrors-edge-catalyst](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mirrors-edge-catalyst)

[image: Looking straight up at the sky where the tops of several high-rise buildings can be seen]
*Mirror's Edge: Catalyst*

---

#### [Contest #74 - Inventory](//meta.arqade.com/q/16529)

**Date:** 2022 - 19th of September, 2022 - 3rd of October | **Winner:** [neonit](//arqade.com/users/236648/neonit?tab=profile) | **Game:** [fallout-3](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fallout-3)

[image: Neonits dragon horde in Fallout 3]
*Fallout 3*

---

#### [Contest #75](//meta.arqade.com/q/16529)

**Date:** 2022 - 3rd of October, 2022 - 17th of October | **Winner:** [Batophobia](//arqade.com/users/42984/batophobia?tab=profile) | **Game:** [gears-5](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gears-5)

[image: Enjoying the view in gears-5]
Enjoying the view in [gears-5](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gears-5)

---

**Jump to:**

**→ [#1 - #25](//meta.arqade.com/a/15414)**
**→ [#26 - #50](//meta.arqade.com/a/15451)**
**→ #51 - #75** (You are here)
**→ [#76 - #100](//meta.arqade.com/a/16582)**
**→ [#101 - #125](//meta.arqade.com/a/16934)**

Answer (score 3):

### Screenshot of the Week Winners #101 - #125

**→ [#1 - #25](//meta.arqade.com/a/15414)**
**→ [#26 - #50](//meta.arqade.com/a/15451)**
**→ [#51 - #75](//meta.arqade.com/a/16149)**
**→ [#76 - #100](//meta.arqade.com/a/16582)**
**→ #101 - #125** (You are here)

---

#### [Contest #101](//meta.arqade.com/q/16921)

**Date:** 2023, 17th October - 31st October
**Winner:** [Artfaith](//arqade.com/users/141102/artfaith?tab=profile) | **Game:** [the-elder-scrolls-online](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-elder-scrolls-online) | **Upvotes:** *10*

[image: Moonlight shines over a hidden temple entrance in a forested gulley]

---

#### [Contest #102 - Halloween](//meta.arqade.com/q/16933)

**Date:** 2023, 31st October - 13th November
**Winner:** [GammaGames](//arqade.com/users/239518/gammagames?tab=profile) | **Game:** [ooblets](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ooblets) | **Upvotes:** *15*

[image: Photo Booth in Ooblets]
*Photo Booth in Ooblets*

---

#### [Contest #103](//meta.arqade.com/q/16943)

**Date:** 2023, 13th November - 27th November
**Winner:** [User 23415](//arqade.com/users/291873/user-23415?tab=profile) | **Game:** [super-mario-odyssey](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/super-mario-odyssey) | **Upvotes:** *14*

[image: Mario relaxing in the wooded kingdom in Super Mario Odyssey]
*Mario relaxing in the wooded kingdom in Super Mario Odyssey*

---

#### [Contest #104](//meta.arqade.com/q/16962)

**Date:** 2023, 27th November - 11th December
**Winner:** [Diego Borba](//arqade.com/users/306358/diego-borba?tab=profile) | **Game:** [dragon-ball-z-kakarot](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dragon-ball-z-kakarot) | **Upvotes:** *14*

[image: Vegeta final explosion]
*Vegeta final explosion*

---

**Jump to:**

**→ [#1 - #25](//meta.arqade.com/a/15414)**
**→ [#26 - #50](//meta.arqade.com/a/15451)**
**→ [#51 - #75](//meta.arqade.com/a/16149)**
**→ [#76 - #100](//meta.arqade.com/a/16582)**
**→ #101 - #125** (You are here)

Answer (score 2):

### Screenshot of the Week Winners #76 - #100

**→ [#1 - #25](//meta.arqade.com/a/15414)**
**→ [#26 - #50](//meta.arqade.com/a/15451)**
**→ [#51 - #75](//meta.arqade.com/a/16149)**
**→ #76 - #100** (You are here)
**→ [#101 - #125](//meta.arqade.com/a/16934)**

---

#### [Contest #76 - Halloween](//gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/16558/)

**Date:** 2022, 17th October - 31st October
**Winner:** [Timmy Jim](//arqade.com/users/163757/timmy-jim?tab=profile) | **Game:** [phasmophobia](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/phasmophobia) | **Upvotes:** *13*

[image: Would you step into the circle in the lobby of Phasmophobia?]
*Would you step into the circle in the lobby of [phasmophobia](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/phasmophobia)?*

---

#### [Contest #77](//gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/16580/)

**Date:** 2022, 1st November - 14th November
**Winner:** [Joachim](//arqade.com/users/222022/joachim?tab=profile) | **Game:** [dishonored-2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dishonored-2) | **Upvotes:** *8*

[image: One of Alexandria Hypatia's examination rooms in the Addermire Institute in dishonored 2]
*One of Alexandria Hypatia's examination rooms in the Addermire Institute in [dishonered-2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dishonered-2)*

---

#### [Contest #78 - Three Years of Screenshot of the Week](//gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/16604/)

**Date:** 2022, 14th November - 28th November
**Winner:** [Wondercricket](//arqade.com/users/124566/wondercricket?tab=profile) | **Game:** [xenoblade-chronicles-3](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/xenoblade-chronicles-3) | **Upvotes:** *9*

[image: Noah and Mio staring off into a beautiful sunset after a major victory, both in-game and emotionally in Xenoblade Chronicles 3]
*Noah and Mio staring off into a beautiful sunset after a major victory, both in-game and emotionally in [xenoblade-chronicles-3](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/xenoblade-chronicles-3)*

---

#### [Contest #79](//gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/16614/)

**Date:** 2022, 28th November - 12th December
**Winner:** [DLosc](//arqade.com/users/287634/dlosc?tab=profile) | **Game:** [dorfromantik](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dorfromantik) | **Upvotes:** *16*

[image: Another day, another charming village created in dorfromantik]
*Another day, another charming village created in [dorfromantik](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dorfromantik)*

---

#### [Contest #80 - Happy Holidays 2022!](//gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/16623/)

**Date:** 2022, 12th December - 26th December
**Winner:** [Batophobia](//arqade.com/users/42984/batophobia?tab=profile) | **Game:** [horizon-zero-dawn](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/horizon-zero-dawn) | **Upvotes:** *12*

[image: Dreaming of a white holiday season in horizon zero dawn]
*Dreaming of a white holiday season in [horizon-zero-dawn](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/horizon-zero-dawn)*

---

#### [Contest #81](//gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/16631/)

**Date:** 2022, 26th December - 2023, 9th January
**Winner:** [Batophobia](//arqade.com/users/42984/batophobia?tab=profile) | **Game:** [stray](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/stray) | **Upvotes:** *12*

[image: Cannot handle the cuteness in stray]
*Cannot handle the cuteness in [stray](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/stray)*

---

#### [Contest #82](//gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/16650/)

**Date:** 2023, 9th January - 23rd January
**Winner:** [Batophobia](//arqade.com/users/42984/batophobia?tab=profile) | **Game:** [xenoblade-chronicles-3](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/xenoblade-chronicles-3) | **Upvotes:** *15*

[image: Love the views in xenoblade chronicles 3]
*Love the views in [xenoblade-chronicles-3](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/xenoblade-chronicles-3)*

---

#### [Contest #83](//gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/16658/)

**Date:**  2023, 23rd January - 6th February
**Winner:** [Batophobia](//arqade.com/users/42984/batophobia?tab=profile) | **Game:** [wonderlands](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wonderlands) | **Upvotes:** *13*

[image: EXPLOSIONS! wonderlands]
*EXPLOSIONS! [wonderlands](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wonderlands)*

---

#### [Contest #84 - Love Declaration/Valentines](//gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/16681/)

**Date:**  2023, 6th February - 20th February
**Winner:** [nobody](//arqade.com/users/281070/nobody?tab=profile) | **Game:** [trails-of-cold-steel-3](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/trails-of-cold-steel-3) | **Upvotes:** *9*

[image: Oz74 unit (called millium) hugs jusis albarea in trails of cold steel 3]
*Oz74 unit (called Millium) hugs Jusis Albarea in [trails-of-cold-steel-3](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/trails-of-cold-steel-3)*

---

#### [Contest #85](//gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/16693/)

**Date:**  2023, 20th February - 6th March
**Winner:** [Batophobia](//arqade.com/users/42984/batophobia?tab=profile) | **Game:** [horizon-zero-dawn](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/horizon-zero-dawn) | **Upvotes:** *12*

[image: horizon-zero-dawn has some awe-inspiring locations]
*[horizon-zero-dawn](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/horizon-zero-dawn) has some awe-inspiring locations*

---

#### [Contest #86 - How Fashionable!](//gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/16707/)

**Date:**  2023, 6th March - 20th March | **Winner:** [SaintWacko](//arqade.com/users/15092/saintwacko?tab=profile) | **Game:** [deep-rock-galactic](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/deep-rock-galactic) | **Upvotes:** *10*

[image: Ready to Rock and Stone in deep rock galactic]
*Ready to Rock and Stone in [deep-rock-galactic](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/deep-rock-galactic)*

---

#### [Contest #87](//gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/16717/)

**Date:**  2023, 20th March - 3rd April
**Winner:** [GammaGames](//arqade.com/users/239518/gammagames?tab=profile) | **Game:** [hogwarts-legacy](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hogwarts-legacy) | **Upvotes:** *10*

[image: Two ghosts out for a late-night dance in hogwarts legacy]
*Two ghosts out for a late-night dance in [hogwarts-legacy](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hogwarts-legacy)*

---

#### [Contest #88 - Easter (Eggs)](//gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/16745/)

**Date:**  2023, 3rd April - 17th April
**Winner:** [Memor-X](//arqade.com/users/30879/memor-x?tab=profile) | **Game:** [final-fantasy-xiv](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/final-fantasy-xiv) | **Upvotes:** *11*

[image: Mih Khetto's Amphitheatre decked out for Hatching-tide 2023 (Eorzea's version of Easter) in final fantasy xiv, featuring a special guest this year, a big Tonberry]
*Mih Khetto's Amphitheatre decked out for Hatching-tide 2023 (Eorzea's version of Easter) in [final-fantasy-xiv](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/final-fantasy-xiv), featuring a special guest this year, a big Tonberry*

---

#### [Contest #89](//gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/16753/)

**Date:** 2023, 17th April - 1st May
**Winner:** [Roddy of the Frozen Peas](//arqade.com/users/44445/roddy-of-the-frozen-peas?tab=profile) | **Game:** [papo-and-yo](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/papo-and-yo) | **Upvotes:** *11*

[image: Quico is just as confused as I am by the architecture in Papo & Yo]
*Quico is just as confused as I am by the architecture in [papo-and-yo](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/papo-and-yo)*

---

#### [Contest #90](//gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/16764/)

**Date:** 2023, 1st May - 15th May
**Winner:** [Roddy of the Frozen Peas](//arqade.com/users/44445/roddy-of-the-frozen-peas?tab=profile) | **Game:** [satisfactory](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/satisfactory) | **Upvotes:** *12*

[image: The beautiful, but rather empty, world of satisfactory]
*The beautiful, but rather empty, world of [satisfactory](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/satisfactory).*

---

#### [Contest #91 - Achievements!](//gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/16773/)

**Date:** 2023, 15th May - 29th May
**Winner:** [Quijibo](//arqade.com/users/145409/quijibo?tab=profile) | **Game:** [tetr.io](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tetr.io) | **Upvotes:** *16*

[image: Perfectly clearing the board set to maximum width on tetr.io (100 blocks wide). Definitely one of the sillier achievements.]
*Perfectly clearing the board set to maximum width on [tetr.io](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tetr.io) (100 blocks wide). Definitely one of the sillier achievements.*

---

#### [Contest #92](//gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/16777/)

**Date:** 2023, 29th May - 13th Jun
**Winner:** [Joachim](//arqade.com/users/222022/joachim?tab=profile) | **Game:** [harts-island](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/harts-island) | **Upvotes:** *13*

[image: Picking up incoherent monologues and strange sights in ben lunato's harts-island:]
*Picking up incoherent monologues and strange sights in ben lunato's [harts-island](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/harts-island)*

---

#### [Contest #93](//gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/16797/)

**Date:** 2023, 13th Jun - 25th Jun
**Winner:** [Joachim](//arqade.com/users/222022/joachim?tab=profile) | **Game:** [metro-exodus](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/metro-exodus) | **Upvotes:** *10*

[image: The first full view of the locomotive Aurora in metro-exodus]
*The first full view of the locomotive Aurora in [metro-exodus](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/metro-exodus)*

---

#### [Contest #94 - Weapon customization](//gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/16817/)

**Date:** 2023, 26th Jun - 10th Jul
**Winner:** [Batophobia](//arqade.com/users/42984/batophobia?tab=profile) | **Game:** [zelda-tears-of-the-kingdom](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/zelda-tears-of-the-kingdom) | **Upvotes:** *9*

[image: Shields need more plush seals zelda-tears-of-the-kingdom]
*Shields need more plush seals [zelda-tears-of-the-kingdom](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/zelda-tears-of-the-kingdom)*

---

#### [Contest #95](//gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/16827/)

**Date:** 2023, 11th Jul - 24th Jul
**Winner:** [SaintWacko](//arqade.com/users/15092/saintwacko?tab=profile) | **Game:** [sea-of-thieves](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sea-of-thieves) | **Upvotes:** *9*

[image: So many shinies on the beach in sea-of-thieves]
*So many shinies on the beach in [sea-of-thieves](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sea-of-thieves)*

---

#### [Contest #96](//gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/16833/)

**Date:** 2023, 25th Jul - 21st Aug
**Winner:** [Roddy of the Frozen Peas](//arqade.com/users/44445/roddy-of-the-frozen-peas?tab=profile) | **Game:** [kena-bridge-of-spirits](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kena-bridge-of-spirits) | **Upvotes:** *10*

[image: Preparing to enter the ruins in kena-bridge-of-spirits.]
*Preparing to enter the ruins in [kena-bridge-of-spirits](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kena-bridge-of-spirits).*

---

#### [Contest #97](//gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/16865/)

**Date:** 2023, 22nd Aug - 3rd Sep
**Winner:** [Artfaith](//arqade.com/users/141102/artfaith?tab=profile) | **Game:** [mirrors-edge-catalyst](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mirrors-edge-catalyst) | **Upvotes:** *12*

[image: Thin hallway between two mirrored surfaces]

---

#### [Contest #98](//gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/16872/)

**Date:** 2023, 4th Sep - 17th Sep
**Winner:** [Joachim](//arqade.com/users/222022/joachim?tab=profile) | **Game:** [baldurs-gate-3](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/baldurs-gate-3) | **Upvotes:** *15*

[image: Looking towards the Decrepit Village in the Underdark in baldurs-gate-3.]
*Looking towards the Decrepit Village in the Underdark in [baldurs-gate-3](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/baldurs-gate-3).*

---

#### [Contest #99](//gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/16884/)

**Date:** 2023, 18th Sep - 1st Oct
**Winner:** [Joachim](//arqade.com/users/222022/joachim?tab=profile) | **Game:** [baldurs-gate-3](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/baldurs-gate-3) | **Upvotes:** *10*

[image: The late sunlight of dusk throwing autumnal colours on the floors of the ruins of Rosymorn Monastery, once dedicated to Lathander, currently a distracting entrance to the crèche Y'llek]
*The late sunlight of dusk throwing autumnal colours on the floors of the ruins of Rosymorn Monastery, once dedicated to Lathander, currently a distracting entrance to the crèche Y'llek*

---

#### [Contest #100](//gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/16898/)

**Date:** 2023, 2 Oct - 16th Oct
**Winner:** [Dragonrage](//arqade.com/users/127901/dragonrage?tab=profile) | **Game:** [horizon-forbidden-west](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/horizon-forbidden-west) | **Upvotes:** *12*

[image: While from a recent contest, pinckerman's submission of sunset photography looks amazing.]
*While from a recent contest ([98](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16872/screenshot-of-the-week-98)), [pinckerman](//arqade.com/users/87579/pinckerman?tab=profile)'s submission of sunset photography looks amazing.*

---

**Jump to:**

**→ [#1 - #25](//meta.arqade.com/a/15414)**
**→ [#26 - #50](//meta.arqade.com/a/15451)**
**→ [#51 - #75](//meta.arqade.com/a/16149)**
**→ #76 - #100** (You are here)
**→ [#101 - #125](//meta.arqade.com/a/16934)**