# Unable to zoom in on the Screenshot of the Week widget

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, screenshot-of-the-week, screenshot-widget

I was unable to open a larger resolution version of the current screenshot of the week in a regular way.

Seeing that the current one is mostly text, I wanted to zoom in and read what is written. The only way to do this was by using "view image" from the context menu. The name of submitting user is linked to their profile, though.

Browser: Firefox for Manjaro 85.0.1

Plugins: uBlock Origin, Vim Vixen, Asciidoctor.js Preview and some others

Comment: As a workaround, you can use an extension like [imagus](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/imagus/) on firefox which shows a larger version of the image when you hover on it, [example](https://elixi.re/i/zlpoyrbr.png). If you're on chrome there's probably smth for that too.

Comment: It's not related to browser, the image is simply not a link.

Answer (score 2):

Until this is fixed, another workaround which I'm using myself is to right click the image, and choosing "Open image in new tab": (or its equivalent in your browser, below is for Chrome)

[image: open image in new tab as workaround]

This will open the full size image in a new browser tab.

Comment: 'View Image' on Firefox

Comment: So this means the full resolution image is loaded, even though it appears so small? That seems a little unnecessary..

Comment: @Joachim very true, and totally deserves a new feature request. All it takes is to add single letter to the image URL to use a much smaller version that imgur already pre-build. For example, the current Screenshot of the Week is https://i.stack.imgur.com/rybqs.jpg so they can put https://i.stack.imgur.com/rybqsm.jpg instead to load much smaller version of same image. You want to start the request?

Comment: @ShadowTheVaccinatedWizard Writing it as we speak - with the same solution :)

Answer (score 0):

Zooming in from the widget itself doesn't work for me too, I don't know if this is intended or not.

In a meantime, you can go to "Hall of Fame" meta question and search for this screenshot there: [Screenshot of the Week - Hall of Fame](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14939/screenshot-of-the-week-hall-of-fame)  (this link is also included in the screenshot widget)