# Link the Screenshot of the Week to the original image so we can see it in full size

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, screenshot-of-the-week, hyperlinks, screenshot-widget

I noticed this while browsing the homepage:

[image: screenshot of the week]

I found it interesting and wanted to see the full size image so I can read better, but alas... clicking the image didn't do anything. Only way to see it is by right click and choosing "open image in a new tab".

Can the image please become a link that opens it?

Comment: Related, possible duplicate: [Unable to zoom in on the Screenshot of the Week widget](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/15577/143571). That said, the other question could probably be better if rephrased to be a feature request.

Comment: @Wrigglenite well since other widgets are links, it might be oversight of the developers, i.e. a bug. Maybe have both tags, it's common on MSE, dunno here though.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Update:** Thanks for the feedback, everyone. We addressed this as part of bug duty this week. The change isn't retroactive, but the next time the screenshot of the week is updated, it'll link to its full version.

<s>Based on our [current roadmap](https://stackoverflow.blog/2021/01/28/the-loop-community-public-platform-roadmap-q1-2021/), this isn't work that we will take on, as it doesn't coincide with functional areas that we plan to improve in the near future.</s>

Comment: +1  I went ahead and updated the post, and it works! Thanks a million for making this change.

Comment: Has this been implemented network-wide or just for Arqade?

Comment: Awesome, I didn't notice the edit. Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

Seeing as this has been brought up for the [3rd time](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/15676/28182) now, I'm promoting my [comment](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15588/link-the-screenshot-of-the-week-to-the-original-image-so-we-can-see-it-in-full-s#comment46844_15598) into a full answer, hopefully making it clear just how trivial a fix this is:

Here's the current code for the entire Screenshot widget (grabbed from the page):

```
<div class="s-sidebarwidget mb16 photo-of-the-week">
    <div class="s-sidebarwidget--header">
        Screenshot of the Week
    </div>
    <div class="s-sidebarwidget--content s-sidebarwidget__items">
        <div class="s-sidebarwidget--item d-block ta-center">
            <img class="wmx100" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/d5zVQ.jpg" alt="Overlooking a Frozen Dam in Horizon Zero Dawn">
        </div>
        <div class="s-sidebarwidget--item d-block ta-center">
            <b>Overlooking a Frozen Dam in Horizon Zero Dawn</b> by <a href="/users/144891/arghtype">arghtype</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="s-sidebarwidget--content jc-space-between">
        <a class="mr32" href="https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15682/screenshot-of-the-week-contest-35">Submit your photo</a>
        <a href="https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14939/screenshot-of-the-week-hall-of-fame">Hall of fame</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

The part we care about is the `<img ... />` tag. Here's what it probably looks like in the codebase, with variable names representing the changeable parts:

```
<img class="wmx100" src="@PhotoUrl" alt="@PhotoName">
```

Here's what needs to happen:

```
<a href="@PhotoUrl" target="_blank">
   <img class="wmx100" src="@PhotoUrl" alt="@PhotoName">
</a>
```

That's it.

- Wrap the image in a link (`<a>` tag)
- Set the link's `href` parameter to the same url as the image `src`
- Set the link's `target` parameter to `_blank`, causing the link to open in a new tab.

Comment: Nice, but I'm afraid it's a lost battle. Reminds me of [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/290oO.png)

Comment: It's a shame that no amount of reputation allows for some mild HTML editing :)

Comment: @Shadow - If we ever want something to happen, especially relatively minor changes like this, it helps to have specific, actionable steps that would resolve it, which can then be used at the right time to point the appropriate people at it so it gets done. Despite being terribly confusing, [status-declined] in this case is not a final resting state, it is being used for ['not on Q1 roadmap'](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/361140/361518#comment1205196_361188). Not what I would have done in SE's place, but it is what it is.

Comment: @Joachim It'd be nice if widgets like this could be open-sourced, so the community could submit improvements for SE to review and integrate as they saw fit. Yet another pipe-dream I suppose :)