# Make screenshot of the week click-able

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, screenshot-of-the-week, screenshot-widget

I know I can right-click to open image in a new tab but that might not be known by all visitors.

Is there some unforeseen benefit to showing the small image instead of making it easy for people to enlarge it?

It can be a direct link to the image or some sort of pop-up gallery; just make it easy to enlarge.

[image]