# For which games would you like to see regular events and/or tournaments?

Tags: discussion, community-event

Since we already got two successfully executed ideas for community events from [this meta post](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14681/what-type-of-community-events-would-you-like-to-see), I'd like to expand onto one idea brought up in the answers by [Wrigglenite](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/users/143571/wrigglenite):

> Periodic gaming sessions for multiplayer games and tournaments of some games (PvP, PvE, no VS at all)

A couple of possible games which could be used in either sort of events are also mentioned in [the post](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14715/192392). Since there is a variety of opinions and games out there, I would like to poll the community for the following questions:

1. What type of games do you want to play?
2. Which games specifically do you want to play?
3. Would you watch streams of games / tournaments?

Just answer these questions in an answer to this post or write some free text as you see fit.

Any suggestions, improvements, or general feedback are welcome. Vote for the answer you agree most with or post your own if none of the existing ones fit your personal taste.

Comment: Bringing this up again is good, but I'm not sure that we want to use an external poll for this. We could use votes on answers instead, which would only let registered users vote.

Comment: @Wrigglenite So are you thinking of a single answer per question or per option, e.g. "What type of games do you want to play? - PvP" and "What type of games do you want to play? - PvE"?

Comment: That's not really needed, people can post their preferred answer and then everyone else can vote on that. It's easier that way, everyone's free to add their own choice instead of having to pick from pre-existing choices.

Comment: I updated my post and added my answer, makes sense to keep things here :)

Comment: You could even combine streams from multiple computers so you would have the option to create one stream showing all off the different views. Just doodled a bit around and got a nice small rtmp-nginx-server working.

Comment: My favourites are Minecraft and SMG2. Not really enough for an answer and I don't know if I would participate in anything, because it depends on what is being done in the game, but I just wanted to contribute another voice.

Comment: @FabianRöling do you mean Super Mario Galaxy 2 with SMG2 or another game I'm not aware of? Super Mario Galaxy feels like it is not what you meant.

Comment: @TobiasF. It is Super Mario Galaxy 2. Why would I not mean it? Because it's so different from Minecraft?

Comment: Oh, I understood it as "Play these games in multiplayer", my bad. Now it makes more sense to me.

Answer (score 6):

#### What type of games do you want to play?

Basically anything with a low barrier to entry. For general 'drop in' gameplay we should do multiplayer or party games that don't require continuity in terms of story. (If we get a group of dedicated regulars, we could start looking at those sorts of games too).

#### Which games specifically do you want to play?

- [tf2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tf2), [fortnite-battle-royale](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fortnite-battle-royale) and [csgo](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/csgo) are all fun, free and support larger player numbers.
- The [jackbox-party-pack](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/jackbox-party-pack) series offers multiple party/trivia games and only requires one person to own it (and host a stream) - other players can join the game using a web browser. Most games support 2-8 active players, and some support up to 100 'audience members' who can vote on certain player actions.
- [left-4-dead](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/left-4-dead) has good co-op, versus and survival modes, is fairly cheap and will run decently on most low/mid-range PCs these days.
- [ultimate-chicken-horse](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ultimate-chicken-horse) is hilarious, lots of fun, and a weird mix of coop and vs multiplayer
- Worms is another great versus multiplayer series, [worms-armageddon](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/worms-armageddon) and [worms-world-party](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/worms-world-party) are the best of the bunch.
- [minecraft](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft) could work as a persistent world that anyone can log into at any time. Takes a bit more effort on the admin department though.

#### Would you watch streams of games / tournaments?

Depends how long they go for. I probably won't watch live, but I would definitely check out the VODs or a highlights reel.

Comment: Jackbox party pack can be **very** interesting from what I have seen.

Comment: I miss the old days of L4D and L4D2 :,(

Comment: @TimmyJim I've been playing L4D1 again recently, which is why it was front of my mind when answering this question :). I've been trying to knock a few achievements off my list

Comment: L4D1&2, Vermintide 1&2, and Deep Rock Galactic are all top of my co-op FPS playlist at the moment. Similar, yet varied game play between them. It just depends on what style of game you want.

Comment: FYI Jackbox Party Pack seems to support up to 10,000 audience members.

Comment: @JMac Interesting, although it depends on the (mini)game you're playing within Jackbox

Comment: @Robotnik They seem to advertise it as "Supports an audience of up to 10,000"; do you know where it mentions which minigames cannot have a 10,000 person audience?

Comment: @JMac As far as I'm aware, each game is built by different developers. The platform that Jackbox provides might support 10,000 audience members, and certain games take advantage of that (I think Quiplash might use the full 10,000?) - but a lot of the mini games only support 2-4 or 2-8 players.

Comment: Either case, if we somehow get 10,000 people join us in game we're doing something right! :)

Comment: @Robotnik The number of players and the number of audience members are entirely different for most of the games.  The players actually play the games and answer the questions, etc.  The audience votes on things which have an effect on the game or decide the results typically.

Comment: @JMac - yep that's correct, but again, so long as the mini game actually supports an audience at all - there's a few that don't.

Answer (score 5):

### What type of games do you want to play?

I am fine with either type of games, be it PvP, PvE or something else, but for most of them I prefer to play together with everyone or PvE (Rainbow Six Siege being the exception)

### Which games specifically do you want to play?

- Rainbow Six Siege (PvP / PvE)
- Factorio
- Minecraft
- Satisfactory (sadly no dedicated servers yet)

### Would you watch streams of games / tournaments?

Sure, why not. I would also be willing to play in such streams given I know at least somewhat of the game or have played  before.

Comment: For Rainbow Six Siege, you can also do a lot of minigames apart from playing normally, e.g. loadout randomizer, kapkan lotto (enter at a window and try to hunt down the kapkan if you survive) etc.

Answer (score 2):

I've participated in events like this before and also hosted some... the best results were actually shooters while the 2nd place goes to WoW.

My proposals:

- [counter-strike-source](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/counter-strike-source) or [counter-strike-global-offensive](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/counter-strike-global-offensive) (mods vs users would be a cool game :P)
- [call-of-duty](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/call-of-duty) (any version is fine, but if we have no server it should be MW2 or later)
- [world-of-warcraft](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/world-of-warcraft)
- [minecraft-java-edition](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-java-edition) has already been proposed, but I'm in for that one too. However, we'd need something cool to do. Just building something isn't really special.

To expand on WoW: I've had some cool events with special raids. A Shaman only raid (with the exception of two non-Shaman tanks) or a Monk only raid were the most successful ones. Unfortunately this will be hard for us to organize due to region restrictions.

Comment: UHCs are always a nice community event for Minecraft.